# How can I use the Klingon alphabet symbols?

Tags: symbols, interface, system

**Note:** This functionality is presently missing.  See: [How to add named characters to Mathematica 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54721/121)

---

*Mathematica* apparently supports the Klingon alphabet:

```
MemberQ[$CharacterEncodings, "Klingon"]
```

> True

UnicodeFontMapping.tr excerpt:

> ```
> 0xF8D0        N       15      0x41        # \[KlingonA]
> 0xF8D1        N       15      0x42        # \[KlingonB]
> 0xF8D2        N       15      0x43        # \[KlingonCH]
> 0xF8D3        N       15      0x44        # \[KlingonD]
> 0xF8D4        N       15      0x45        # \[KlingonE]
> 0xF8D5        N       15      0x47        # \[KlingonGH]
> 0xF8D6        N       15      0x48        # \[KlingonH]
> 0xF8D7        N       15      0x49        # \[KlingonI]
> 0xF8D8        N       15      0x4a        # \[KlingonJ]
> 0xF8D9        N       15      0x4c        # \[KlingonL]
> 0xF8DA        N       15      0x4d        # \[KlingonM]
> 0xF8DB        N       15      0x4e        # \[KlingonN]
> 0xF8DC        N       15      0x46        # \[KlingonNG]
> 0xF8DD        N       15      0x4f        # \[KlingonO]
> 0xF8DE        N       15      0x50        # \[KlingonP]
> 0xF8DF        N       15      0x4b        # \[KlingonQ]
> 0xF8E0        N       15      0x51        # \[KlingonQH]
> 0xF8E1        N       15      0x52        # \[KlingonR]
> 0xF8E2        N       15      0x53        # \[KlingonS]
> 0xF8E3        N       15      0x54        # \[KlingonT]
> 0xF8E4        N       15      0x58        # \[KlingonTLH]
> 0xF8E5        N       15      0x55        # \[KlingonU]
> 0xF8E6        N       15      0x56        # \[KlingonV]
> 0xF8E7        N       15      0x57        # \[KlingonW]
> 0xF8E8        N       15      0x59        # \[KlingonY]
> 0xF8E9        N       15      0x27        # \[KlingonGlottalStop]
> 0xF8F0        N       15      0x29        # \[Klingon0]
> 0xF8F1        N       15      0x21        # \[Klingon1]
> 0xF8F2        N       15      0x40        # \[Klingon2]
> 0xF8F3        N       15      0x23        # \[Klingon3]
> 0xF8F4        N       15      0x34        # \[Klingon4]
> 0xF8F5        N       15      0x25        # \[Klingon5]
> 0xF8F6        N       15      0x5e        # \[Klingon6]
> 0xF8F7        N       15      0x26        # \[Klingon7]
> 0xF8F8        N       15      0x2a        # \[Klingon8]
> 0xF8F9        N       15      0x28        # \[Klingon9]
> 0xF8FF        N       15      0x5a        # \[KlingonEmpire]
> ```

**What font and settings do I need to make these visible?**

---

Klingon alphabet:
[image: Klingon alphabet]

Klingon numerals:
[image: Klingon numerals]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I installed a pIqaD font (only these map Unicode private range 0xF8D0..0xF8FF to Klingon characters, but that did not help Mathematica render these characters. Is there a configuration file that maps character range to a particular font? I think Mathematica does not try very earnestly to map code points to available fonts in the system. (This is in Windows 7).

Comment: "Note Mathematica not only supports a wide variety of international languages, but it also supports Klingon making it, I believe, the first intergalactic software program." --- from [this review of Mma 4.0 in 1999!](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.15/15.08/Mathematica40/index.html)

Comment: You are aiming at [Klingon Boggle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HPFRYVJ63A), right?

Comment: @Yves oh no my secret is out!

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new Klingon overlords ;-)

Comment: how do you write a letter k in klingon

Comment: The same way that you write a letter Щ or ش in the Latin alphabet...

Comment: @davidpatterson by typing the literal character name e.g. `\[KlingonV]`; you could add input aliases, e.g. local to a new Notebook: `CreateDocument[{}, InputAliases -> {"kv" -> \[KlingonV]}]` then [Esc]`kv`[Esc]

Comment: Ok, so you are telling me, that the MATHEMATICAL software supports Klingon characters, but not irreducible characters...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson [It no longer does](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54721/121) if that makes you feel better.  Incidentally which characters are you missing? Could you give an example of the representation you wish to implement?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Well, I play around a lot with Schur polynomials, which are characters of GLn, and also irreducible characters of Sn. In general, I would like access to structure constants, such as Littlewood-Richardson coefficients, Kostka coefficients and Kronecker coefficients.

My question about generating Gelfand-Tsetlin patterns on this site can be used to compute Kostka numbers, for example. LR-coefficients can be computed by counting lattice points in polytopes, another thing I really think Mathematica could be better at.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution.  *Mathematica* is set up to use the font [KLIpIqaDmey](http://www.neutralzone.de/archiv/dload/KLIPIqaDmey.zip).  The tip-off is in the `UnicodeFontMapping.tr` file referenced in the question.  The header reads:

```
@@resource UnicodeFontMapping
Mathematica: Times Automatic
Mathematica: (Times Courier) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica1 Mathematica1Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica2 Mathematica2Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica3 Mathematica3Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica4 Mathematica4Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica5 Mathematica5Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica6 Mathematica6Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica7 Mathematica7Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: MathematicaInternal Automatic
Mathematica: Zapf_Dingbats Automatic
Mathematica: (DefaultKanjiFont DefaultMonoKanjiFont) Japanese
Mathematica: (DefaultKoreanFont DefaultMonoKoreanFont) Korean
Mathematica: (DefaultChineseSimplifiedFont DefaultMonoChineseSimplifiedFont) ChineseSimplified
Mathematica: (DefaultChineseTraditionalFont DefaultMonoChineseTraditionalFont) ChineseTraditional
Mathematica: KLIpIqaDmey Klingon



#  0  =  special: dynamically assigned
#  1  =  base font
#  2  =  Mathematica1: Greek letters and common operators
#  3  =  Mathematica2: Radicals, brackets, integrals, arrows
#  4  =  Mathematica3: Operators and shapes
#  5  =  Mathematica4: Arrows, vectors, over/under brackets, keys, icons
#  6  =  Mathematica5: the archaic alphabets, Script
#  7  =  Mathematica6: Gothic
#  8  =  Mathematica7: DoubleStruck
#  9  =  FE Internal
#  10  =  Zapf Dingbats
#  11  =  Kanji (if present)
#  12  =  Korean (if present)
#  13  =  Chinese Simplified (if present)
#  14  =  Chinese Traditional (if present)
#  15  =  Klingon (if present)
```

At first glance I overlooked the significance of the `Mathematica:` lines, but then I realized their relation to 0 - 15 below.

Image captured from *Mathematica* with the font installed:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

The way to get those characters is to type their long name in the form specified in the right hand column of that table.  I don't know what it's supposed to look like, but to me they look just like a smaller variant of the latin alphabet.

```
In[39]:= ToCharacterCode["\[KlingonA]\[KlingonB]\[KlingonCH]\
\[KlingonD]\[KlingonGlottalStop]\[Klingon4]\[KlingonEmpire]"]

Out[39]= {63696, 63697, 63698, 63699, 63721, 63732, 63743}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to downvote this.  Yes that is the entry form, but I think it's quite apparent that the glyphs are not correct. :-/

Comment: It's only apparent if one knows Klingon... :)

Comment: Like I said, I am sorry.  I stress that I am downvoting the answer, *not* the answerer.  For what it's worth I found a solution.  See below.

Comment: All the Klingons I know agree that this answer is not wrong.