# Pattern matching deletion of list items

Tags: pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove B -> A from a list if A -> B is in the list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/how-can-i-remove-b-a-from-a-list-if-a-b-is-in-the-list)

I'm working toward building a graph and use some code to construct my rules which results in a form as follows:

```
g = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 2}
```

I would like to delete all reverse duplicate entries form the list, i.e. both `1->2` and `2->1` appear in the list.  I would like to get rid of one of them and do this for all reverse duplicates in the list `g`.

Comment: All: please try a bit harder to find duplicate questions; thank you.

Comment: @Tom That case is already covered by my own answer to the previous question.  If you feel that this closure was in error feel free to vote to reopen.  IMHO the fact that identical answers were posted indicates it is a true duplicate.  (ps. please use the `@name` notification when responding; I didn't see your message until now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This satisfies your needs

```
DeleteDuplicates @ (Sort /@ g)
```

> ```
> {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4}
> ```

Comment: Kind of a waste to `f @ (stuff)` when you can just `f[stuff]`, no?

Comment: Well, no unnecessary signs :  `Sort /@ g // DeleteDuplicates `

Comment: @J.M. I also use this kind of `@(...)` syntax because of reasons given [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6338/89). By removing the head you don't have to jump to the end to remove `]`.

Comment: @István: still bloody ugly for me. To each his own, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

`Union[Sort /@ g]` seems to be what you need...