# Operations on sets of sets

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove B -> A from a list if A -> B is in the list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/how-can-i-remove-b-a-from-a-list-if-a-b-is-in-the-list)
>   [Delete duplicate elements from list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/delete-duplicate-elements-from-list)
>   [Pattern matching deletion of list items](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/pattern-matching-deletion-of-list-items)

How do I delete the duplicates of a set who's elements are themselves sets?

Here is an example:
Deleting the duplicates from {{x,y},{y,x}} should give {{x,y}} (or {{y,x}}, both answers are equivalent).

I am particularly interested in the case when x and y are lists, but a solution that works for x and y of any type would be better.

Comment: Actually, the title should be: "Operations on lists of sets", as your example is not a set (though the outer list does contain sets).

Comment: @István The top and second level data structures have the same data type, so I think it should either be "...lists of lists" or "...sets of sets".  I picked the latter to emphasize that I am thinking of them as sets even though the actual data type in Mathematica is a list.

Comment: It is not clear for me what are you expecting from deleting duplicates from `{{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}}`. Should it be `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}` or `{1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Pattern matching deletion of list items](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7525/245) which itself was a duplicate of [How can I remove B -> A from a list if A -> B is in the list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/245).

Comment: This might answer your question, too: [How to use Union on list of lists without sorting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-to-use-union-on-list-of-lists-without-sorting-them-first/)

Comment: @Jens, Artes: I don't think it is a direct duplicate of any of those, as it deals with **sets** instead of lists, therefore here even `{2, 1}` equals `{1, 2}`, which means that a simple `DeleteDuplicates` is not enough. If anything, then Thies' answer could be the source, and those voting for closing should point to that post.

Comment: @IstvánZachar but look at Artes solution [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7528/245) - exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Jens: I yield.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ {{2, 1}, {1, 2}}]
```

help?

**Edit :**  ( Just try your data - `Mathematica` is cool, isn't it ? )

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ {{x, y}, {y, x}}]
```

Comment: Sorry for the misleading example.  I clarified the question and example to make it clear that the elements of the inner sets are not integers.

Comment: Just try it with your data.

Comment: Weird, I had tried it, but I thought it gave me the wrong answer.  It is working now though, so thanks!

Comment: I see.  I think the order of operations tricked me and it executed the `Sort /@` part sooner than I wanted. Adding parentheses to force the correct order fixed that.

Comment: Glad you could figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on `Union` and its option `SameTest` :

```
Union[{{x, y}, {y, x}}, SameTest -> (Union[#1] == Union[#2] &)]
```

> ```
> {{x, y}}
> ```

```
Union[{{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}}, SameTest -> (Union[#1] == Union[#2] &)]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 1}}
> ```

In case of more nested lists I would use `Flatten` on appropriate level, e.g.

```
Union @ Flatten[{ {{2, 1}}, {{1, 2}} }, 2]
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

where `DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ { {{2, 1}}, {{1, 2}} }]` does not work if we don't use `Flatten`.  However, this is not a general solution, one has to consider appropriate examples and work on case by case basis.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading example. I clarified the question and example to make it clear that the elements of the inner sets are not integers.

Comment: Pardon me but this does not delete duplicate sets: deleting duplicates from `{{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}}` should result in `{{1,2}, {1,3}}`, as those are the two distinct sets, but `Union@Flatten[{{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}}]` returns `{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: @TysonWilliams Does it satisfy your needs ?  Otherwise, could you give an appropriate example ?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks for reporting the problem. I updated the answer. If you see another problems, let me know about them. Nethertheless, I hope it is a good alternative to ruebenko's answer, which is not too general, either .

Comment: @Artes: Nice use of `SameTest`!