# How do I mimic the functionality of "<>"?

Tags: custom-notation, boxes

The Cell expression for:

```
<>
```

is

```
Cell[BoxData["<>"], "Input"]
```

However similar expressions are parsed into RowBox(s), for example:

```
><

Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{">", "<"}]], "Input"]
```

How do I get expressions like >< to act like <> does?

Comment: My bet is you can't. Operators are predefined and I definately hope someone proves me wrong

Comment: You could probably put something together with `InterpretationBox` and `MakeBoxes`

Comment: @R.M I will look into it last time I tried to use InterpretationBox I ran into a dead end.

Answer (score 3):

[Michael Pilat has stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305511/618728) that you cannot create your own compound operators.

You may find some utility in these posts:

[Prefix operator with low precedence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6338/121)

[How can one define an infix operator with an arbitrary unicode character?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6355/121)

Comment: Shouldn't it be closed as a duplicate then?

Comment: @R.M which one where?

Answer (score 2):

Are you interested only in the case of "less than" and "greater than" symbols? Might other variations serve the purpose?

The following parentheses are represented like  "<>" (they are represented without using `RowBox`), regardless of the order of the characters:

[image: parentheses]