# Modular arithmetic in Mathematica?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to implement something like `1 + 1 = 0`; i.e., simple modular arithmetic in *Mathematica*.

This seems like it should be a really easy built-in option, but I can't find any info on it anywhere. I think probably I'm just overlooking something.

Really there *should* just be an option for `Plus`. But `Options[Plus]` gives `{ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing [Rojo's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo) idea from
[Is it possible to define custom compound assignment operators like ⊕= similar to built-ins +=, *= etc?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27081), we can construct a modular addition operator.

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{lhs_, rest : PatternSequence[SubscriptBox["⊕", m_], _] ..}],
   StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[{{lhs, rest}[[1 ;; ;; 2]], m}, 
   StandardForm] /. {x_, HoldComplete[mod_]} :> 
   HoldComplete@Mod[Total[x /. HoldComplete[a_] :> a], mod]
```

Examples

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Circle-plus can be entered with <kbd>ESC</kbd> `c+` <kbd>ESC</kbd> or `\[CirclePlus]`.  A subscript can be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>`_` (underscore).

One could do something similar with `\[CircleTimes]` and modular multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out on my own. Wanted to post the solution in case anyone else ran into the same problem. It's just:

```
Mod[a + b, x]
```

so that

```
Mod[1 + 1, 2]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Pretty straightforward actually.