# Best choice for an infix join operator?

Tags: custom-notation

I would love some advice for what symbol to use and best implement it?

```
<< Notation`;
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"x_", " ", "jn", " ", "y_", " "}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{" ", RowBox[{"Join", "[", RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y_"}], "]"}]}]]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~Join~` can already serve as an infix operator.  If you want something more concise I recommend choosing one of the [existing operators without a built-in meaning.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html)  Simply:

```
UnionPlus = Join;

{1, 2}⊎{3, 4, 5}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

(Use [`InputAliases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases.html) for fast entry.)

If there are none there that you like you might use Rojo's method from [Is it possible to define custom compound assignment operators like ⊕= similar to built-ins +=, *= etc?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27081/is-it-possible-to-define-custom-compound-assignment-operators-like-%E2%8A%95-similar-to/39703#39703)