# Shorthand for map at level 2

Tags: expression-manipulation, custom-notation

I love the shorthand `/@`. It is amazing for readability (and laziness when typing). However, right now I find that I need Map at level 2, i.e. `Map[f, List[List[a,b],List[c,d]], {2}]`, a lot and I'd wish there was a similar shorthand notation available for a map at level 2. Is there? If not, can we make one?

Comment: `Map[f] /@ {{1, 2}}`? you can always define new function `map2[f,l]`.

Comment: @Kuba. That's the usefulness of operator forms that I've been waiting for. My answer is silly.

Comment: @march I disagree, your answer is not silly but the canonical approach to this problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. After reading the Performance section of your post, I see what you mean. Kuba's answer seemed elegant, and I did not expect the possible performance issues.

Comment: @march I'd say my example is interesting but I wouldn't use it either :) This syntax doesn't scale and is incosistent in having both `Map` and `/@`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Corrected to use `SubscriptBox` as Rojo showed and [Kvothe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45020/kvothe) commented, fixing binding.*

Rojo shows a way in [Is it possible to define custom compound assignment operators like ⊕= similar to built-ins +=, *= etc?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27081/is-it-possible-to-define-custom-compound-assignment-operators-like-%E2%8A%95-similar-to/39703#39703)

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{f_, SubscriptBox["/@", n_], expr_}], StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression @ RowBox[{"Map", "[", f, ",", expr, ",", "{", n, "}", "]"}]
```

Now, entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>:

[image]

I actually used this (or code very like it) for a while but I got tired of having to translate to the long form for posting here so I stopped.

You could use a variation of you want to allow for full *levelspec* rather map at (only) level *n*.

---

### Performance

Syntactically I like Kuba's suggestion of `Map[f] /@ expr` but I have personally rejected this as a general replacement for `Map[f, expr, {2}]`, and I would like to illustrate why.

An aside: the only reason I am offering this critique is because I find this form *desirable*; I had the same reaction as march, just longer ago: "*That's the usefulness of operator forms that I've been waiting for.*"  I still *hope* that at least the performance aspect will be improved in future versions.

Unfortunately in the current implementation (or at least 10.1.0, but I don't think this has changed in v11) Operator Forms cannot themselves be compiled, therefore `Map[f] /@ expr` forces unpacking of `expr`.  To make a contrived example where the Operator Form is at a stark disadvantage I shall use an array of many rows and few columns.

```
big = RandomReal[1, {500000, 3}];

Map[Sin] /@ big     // RepeatedTiming // First

Map[Sin, big, {2}]  // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.16
>
> 0.0482
> ```

```
On["Packing"];
Map[Sin] /@ big;
```

> Unpacking array with dimensions {500000,3} to level 1. >>
>
> Unpacking array with dimensions {3}. >>
>
> Unpacking array with dimensions {3}. >>
>
> Unpacking array with dimensions {3}. >>
>
> Further output of Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1 will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

As [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp) commented one can see that the Operator Form is the problem here by comparing:

```
On["Packing"]

Sin /@ # & /@ big; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0765
> ```

Here `Sin /@ # &` compiles and the operation is fast and no unpacking takes place.

#### Evaluation

At risk of belaboring a point there is another limitation or at least difference regarding `Map[f] /@ expr`: evaluation.

Compare:

```
Map[f, Hold[{a}, b, c], {2}]

Map[f] /@ Hold[{a}, b, c]
```

> ```
> Hold[{f[a]}, b, c]
>
> Hold[Map[f][{a}], Map[f][b], Map[f][c]]
> ```

Clearly these operations are not equivalent.

Comment: And its may be beside the point, but the `Listable` `Sin[big]` is yet a further order of magnitude faster. By the way, what about `f /@ # & /@ expr` in terms of unpacking? The operator form seems to unpack completely, while the stringed mapping operators unpack only one level?

Comment: Great, thank you. One question: Do I understand correctly that your solution at the top of your post does not take a performance hit? 

Also I don't know whether this might depend on the version or setup ,but my mathematica will try to complete my expression wrongly if I use the superscript (it will change the expression to (f /@)^2, so to avoid this inconvenience I changed the Superscript to a Subscript.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP (1) Yes of course, re: #4 in [(7925)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7925/121); I did warn that the example was contrived.  (2) Yes `Sin /@ # & /@ big` is much better and I should have included that example as that was actually a key point: it is the Operator Form that interferes with this application.

Comment: @Kvothe The overhead of this method manifests in a different place; see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39675/121 for one example of this.  A single rule like this should have negligible overhead and I now prefer this method (as commented to Rojo) to using the Notation Package for this reason.  (2) You're absolutely right and I mucked this up.  For some reason I remembered it being Superscript despite Rojo's code, then I was surprised by the need to select `/@` before entering the superscript to enforce binding (which I *did* mention by the way).  I'll change this to Subscript. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes I see that you did mention that. Sorry, glancing over it I thought you were just explaining how to do superscripts (I thought: "wow he's really making it newbie ready") and I did not pay enough attention to it.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not aware of a simple one, but perhaps you could make your own? The following is not great because it requires you to enter `CenterDot` as <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, and you can't control the precedence, but depending on your use-case, it might be useful. In addition, you can use whatever built-in symbol with no built-in meaning you want:

```
CenterDot[f_, a_] := Map[f, a, {2}]
```

Then:

### [image]

The `CenterDot` operator has no associativity which means that a string of input like `a·b·c·d` will be translated as `CenterDot[a, b, c, d]` which has no rule:

```
a·b·c·d // FullForm
```

> ```
> CenterDot[a, b, c, d]
> ```

For this reason it is desirable to manually establish associativity:

```
CenterDot[a__, b_, c_] := a·(b·c)
```

Now:

```
a·Row[{b}]·Row[{c}]·Row[{d}]
```

> ```
> a[b[c[d]]]    (*  Row[{a[Row[{b}][Row[{c}][d]]]}]  *)
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask a few follow up questions. I've already used CenterDot (for an innerproduct where this symbol is conventional and thus very good for readability ). Are there good alternatives available , i.e. not to crazy a precedence, a short esc esc shorthand. (I did look in the documentation for Operators without Built‐in Meanings, but it does not give a complete list. (Which I find strange, is there something I don't understand about how the Mathematica documentation works?)

Comment: @Kvothe I don't know why that page is incomplete; I believe http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html is a better reference.  Try `SmallCircle`, shorthand entered Esc `sc` Esc.

Comment: @Kvothe The `Precedence` function may be useful as well; see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/121 for a few examples.  Beware that its output is sometimes conflicting however.

Comment: march I made an extension to your answer, hopefully correctly after a second attempt.  I think it is an important point to address.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks for the extension. That makes good sense to do and isn't really something I would have thought of.