# Nested RowBox in MakeExpression reports error when I define my own curl operator, but the single RowBox in MakeExpression works well

Tags: syntax, operators, notation

I want to define my own vector notation so that the input `\[Del] \[Cross] a` outputs `curl[a]` while the `curl` is a custom function. I would like to use the `MakeExpression` method like the relating [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27081/is-it-possible-to-define-custom-compound-assignment-operators-like-%E2%8A%95-similar-to). But I failed when using the nested `RowBox` in `MakeExpression`:

```
In[1]:= MakeExpression[RowBox[{"\[Del]", RowBox[{"\[Cross]", a_}]}], StandardForm] :=  MakeExpression[RowBox[{"curl", "[", a, "]"}], StandardForm];
\[Del]\[Cross]a // FullForm
Output Error:  Curl: \[Del]\[Cross]a cannot be interpreted. In a curl, the del operator requires a subscript with differentiation variables.
```

However, the single `RoxBox` in `MakeExpression` works as what I thought:

```
In[2]:= MakeExpression[RowBox[{"\[Del]", "\[Cross]", a_}], StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression[RowBox[{"curl", "[", a, "]"}], StandardForm] ;
\[Del]\[Cross]a // FullForm
Out[2] = curl[a]
```

What is the exact differences between the two solutions above? They just have the same `DisplayForm`:

```
RowBox[{"\[Del]", RowBox[{"\[Cross]", a}]}] // DisplayForm
RowBox[{"\[Del]", "\[Cross]", a}] // DisplayForm
```

Why the first solution using nested `RowBox` in `MakeExpression` reports error?

Answer (score 0):

They may have the same `DisplayForm`, but the underlying box structure is different. Type `\[Del]\[Cross]a`, then click `Cell > Show Expression` to see the box structure. It is all in one `RowBox`.

[image]