# Piping and Replacement

Tags: replacement

I haven't been able to figure out how to use piping with certain functions. Specifically, I would like to apply a replacement at the end of a pipe, like the following:

```
(x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 /. {y -> x/2} // Expand /. {z -> E^x}
```

Also, is there a general rule that I should know about piping that would help me in the future with problems like this?

Comment: `Postfix (//)` has low precedence, and `Prefix (@)` has high precedence. [tutorial/OperatorInputForms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) has additional details that may be  useful.

Comment: The choice of relative precedence of `//` and `/.` is poor, I feel.

Comment: Although it may look like piping // isn't actually a pipe in the same way as | in UNIX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not have a rule, other than to suggest using `()` for grouping, like this

```
((x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 /. {y -> x/2} // Expand) /. {z -> E^x}    
(* x^2/4 + x^3 + x^4 + x Log[E^x] + 2 x^2 Log[E^x] + Log[E^x]^2 *)
```

A `()` pair is not always needed, like here

```
(x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 /. {y -> x/2}      /. z -> E^x
```

But if you not sure, just do it all the time. It won't hurt

```
(  (x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 /. {y -> x/2}  )    /. z -> E^x
```

The above gives the same answer, but it has `()` to make sure the grouping is as intended.

Answer (score 8):

As a rule I would avoid following `// function` with anything but another `// function2` due to [the precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) of `//`.  The very property that makes `//` convenient to follow code with (grouping the left-hand side) makes it difficult to follow *it* with anything else, because binding looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If your style demands it I suggest you configure your code such that your string of operations is done inside functions, e.g.:

```
a + b + c // f1 // (# /. c -> 2 &)
```

Or form a compound function:

```
a + b + c // (f1[##] /. c -> 2 &)
```

This adds semantic complexity, and it would be cleaner of course to just write:

```
f1[a + b + c] /. c -> 2
```

It might also suit your style to use different operators, though at the moment I cannot see how that would directly solve your style issue.  As an example see:

[Prefix operator with low precedence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6338/121)

---

It occurs to me that if you have if the operators that you wish to string after `//` match a certain pattern this might be accomplished with something like this:

```
SetAttributes[Colon, HoldAll]
Colon[lhs_, h_[f : _Symbol | _Function, rest__]] := f[lhs] ~h~ rest
```

Now:

```
a + b + c \[Colon] f1 /. c -> 2
a + b + c \[Colon] f1 + q + r + s
```

which displays as:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

yields:

```
f1[2 + a + b]

q + r + s + f1[a + b + c]
```

This however fails and would require a more complicated definition:

```
a + b + c \[Colon] f1 + q + r + s /. c -> 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Combining the infix forms of *Mathematica*'s functions with the prefix or postfix forms of other functions can get tricky. One must pay careful attention of the rules of precedence for each operator form. Here are two tips on what to do when a complex combination of operators does work as expected.

- Retreat. Enter the expression or part of the expression in normal form. In your case, I would would retreat to

  ```
  Expand[(x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 /. y -> x/2] /. z -> E^x
  ```

Now there is little doubt about what the order of evaluation will be.

- Wrap the expression with `Hold`  and `InputForm` and evaluate that, which will show you how *Mathematica*  brackets the expression. Applying this to your expression:

  ```
  InputForm[Hold[(x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 /. y -> x/2 // Expand /. z -> E^x]]
  ```

  > ```
  > Hold[(Expand /. z -> E^x)[(x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 /. y -> x/2]]
  > ```

Now you can clearly see what is going wrong with your expression.

Answer (score 3):

Using the new in M10 operator forms will help. For example:

```
(x^2 + y + Log[z])^2 // ReplaceAll[y -> x/2] // Expand // ReplaceAll[z -> E^x]
```

> x^2/4 + x^3 + x^4 + x Log[E^x] + 2 x^2 Log[E^x] + Log[E^x]^2