# Can I define a "postfix map" operator with comparable precedence behavior to //

Tags: custom-notation

I am trying to define a "postfix map" operator (denoted `$OP$` for now) that behaves thus:

```
{1, 2, 3} $OP$ # + 1 & == {2, 3, 4}
```

and

```
{1, 2, 3} // RotateLeft $OP$ # + 1 & == {3, 4, 2}
```

and

```
{1, 2, 3} // RotateLeft $OP$ # + 1 & // Total == 9
```

I hope not to need parentheses when I pipe results forward using a combination of // and my custom `$OP$`. Is this possible? My guess is that it is not because there is no operator with the same precedence as `//`.

I understand that I will need to use either an unassigned operator (e.g., CirclePlus) or another symbol as an infix operator; that I cannot modify precedence; and that the ability to define custom syntax is limited (e.g., `@//` can't be defined).

Looking at "Operator Input Forms", it seems the closest I can get to `//` with regard to precedence is either Colon or VerticalSeparator, as

```
Precedence /@ {Colon, Postfix, VerticalSeparator} == {80., 70., 60.}
```

**Does this mean that there is simply no way to define the operator I seek in a way that will never require parentheses when it is chained with `//`?**

For example, given

```
SetAttributes[VerticalSeparator, HoldAll];
VerticalSeparator[l_, f_] := f /@ l;
```

this does not work

```
{1, 2, 3} \[VerticalSeparator] # + 1 & // Total == {(1 + #1)[1], (1 + #1)[2], (1 + #1)[3]}
```

Similarly, with

```
SetAttributes[Colon, HoldAll];
Colon[l_, f_] := f /@ l;
```

this does not work

```
{1, 2, 3} // RotateLeft \[Colon] # + 1 & == {2, 3, 1}
```

I have read, for example, [Prefix operator with low precedence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/prefix-operator-with-low-precedence) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304858/custom-postfix-notation-apply-function .

Comment: In your two examples, you use the precedence of the operator in a manner opposite to what you want to achieve. Note that `|` has lower precedence than `//`, yet you use it in a situation where it needs to be higher. Likewise, `:` has a higher precedence, but your example puts it in a situation where you need it to be lower. You can't have it both ways, so you need to pick one. These work: `{1, 2, 3} // RotateLeft \[VerticalSeparator] # + 1 &` and `{1, 2, 3} \[Colon] # + 1 & // Total` (i.e., just switch the two). In addition, your definition for `:` is incorrect — you haven't used a pattern.

Comment: According to @rm-rf's comment this is the simple extension of the above linked duplicate, with the added mistake of switching the operators.

Comment: Just to clarify, my hope was to define an operator that would before or after. The two examples were meant to show that as far as I can tell it won't work both ways. I just wanted to confirm I hadn't missed something. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: `{1, 2, 3} // RotateLeft \[VerticalSeparator] # + 1 == {2, 3, 1} &` works as I would expect, but it doesn't produce output I would consider useful.  The problem does not appear to be `\[VerticalSeparator]` but something else.  Perhaps you should say what "works" means, that is, what output you expect.

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to write in the form `list // do something to whole list \[Colon] do something to each element // do something to whole list \[Colon] do something to each element // etc.`