# How to construct custom operators with precedence?

Tags: programming, operators, custom-notation, precedence

I need to combine data structures in operations analogous to addition, subtraction, multiplication and division (and more). I need more than one operation of each type, i.e. more than one method of addition, subtraction, etc. I have made some progress. Using the Notation palette, i can for example define `!/!` and `%/%` as different operators for division. But how can I set precedence? My impression is that this is not possible. I have explored the existing symbols without in-built meanings, such as `CirclePlus` and `CircleMinus`. These symbols without in-built meanings have precedence while allowing the meaning to be defined by the user. But I can't find enough of them to meet my needs. For example, there is no "`CircleDivide`".

Might it be possible to use subscripts and have $/_a$ and $/_b$ for different types of division while retaining the precedence of the division operator? If I could do it for division, then I could do it for the other operators of interest too.

ADDENDUM:
I've made some progress following [the clue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74089/how-to-construct-custom-operators-with-precedence/96262#comment203229_74089) provided by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard). The following code creates subscripted operators for operations analogous to `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`. The `conv` functions are highly simplified for test purposes and in the actual application would perform operations on data structures.

```
In[1]:= conv[x_, y_, op_ /; op == "+" || op == "-"] := Module[{},
If[op == "-", Return[conv[x, -y, "+"]]]; x + y]

conv[x_, y_, op_ /; op == "*" || op == "/"] := Module[{},
If[op == "/", Return[conv[x, 1/y, "*"]]]; x y]

MakeExpression[RowBox[{x_, SubscriptBox["+", "i"], y_}], StandardForm] := 
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"conv", "[", x, ",", y, ",", "\"+\"", "]"}], StandardForm]
MakeExpression[RowBox[{x_, SubscriptBox["-", "i"], y_}], StandardForm] := 
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"conv", "[", x, ",", y, ",", "\"-\"", "]"}], StandardForm]
MakeExpression[RowBox[{x_, SubscriptBox["*", "i"], y_}], StandardForm] := 
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"conv", "[", x, ",", y, ",", "\"*\"", "]"}], StandardForm]
MakeExpression[RowBox[{x_, SubscriptBox["/", "i"], y_}], StandardForm] := 
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"conv", "[", x, ",", y, ",", "\"/\"", "]"}], StandardForm]
```

Testing the code, it works at least up to a point and the subscripted operators appear to have the same precedence as the parent operators (`+`,`*`, etc.):

[image: test 1]

However, if I remove the parentheses from the second test expression, I get an error message. Why is that occurring and how do I fix it?

[image: test 2]

Comment: If you look at [Mr.Wizard's answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6341/245), and the linked post, the prospects for doing what you want seem to be rather dim.

Comment: @Jens: I had seen the statement that compound operators cannot have custom precedence, but I wondered if an existing operator (plus, minus, times, etc) might retain its precedence if used with a subscript. I have experimented but am not very proficient at defining notations and so far can't get a subscripted operator to call a function at all, whereas I was able to get non-subscripted custom operators like !*! to do so.

Comment: @Duns I believe you are looking for this: [(39703)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39703/121).  I cannot recall with certainty what the precedence of the "new" operators is and I don't have time to experiment, but I *think* it tracks the "parent" operator.  Please test that and let me know if it will suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction of custom operators with precedence is described in the [Complex Patterns and Advanced Features](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/ComplexPatternsAndAdvancedFeatures.html#4576917) Notation Package Tutorial. More general informations can be found in [Precedence of Operators in Notations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/PrecedenceOfOperatorsInNotations.html#112725058).

The following operator definitions work for the examples given in the question.
First loading the [Notation Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html):

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

Now I'll add an `InputAlias` for each operator, although this increases the convenience only for $-_i$ significantly.

```
AddInputAlias["+i" -> ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["+", "i"]]]

AddInputAlias["*i" -> ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["*", "i"]]]

AddInputAlias["/i" -> ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["/", "i"]]]

AddInputAlias["-i" -> ParsedBoxWrapper[
 TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"], Minus, SyntaxForm -> "a"]]]
```

Using the Notation Palette this looks like
[image: AddInputAlias]
First I'll define the infix operators with some not yet defined functions

```
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["+", "i"]], myPlus]

InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["*", "i"]], myTimes]

InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["/", "i"]], myDivision]

InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
  TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"], Minus, SyntaxForm -> "a"]], myMinus]
```

[image: InfixNotation]

For a first test, your testing code in a copyable format

```
\!\(\(9 \*TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"],Minus,SyntaxForm->"a"] 2\*SubscriptBox[\(*\), \(i\)]3\)\*SubscriptBox[\(+\), \(i\)]\(4\*SubscriptBox[\(/\), \(i\)]2\)\)

\!\(4\*SubscriptBox[\(+\), \(i\)]\(6\*SubscriptBox[\(*\), \(i\)]2\*SubscriptBox[\(/\), \(i\)]4\)\)
```

which can be easily typed in using the `InputAlias`es or the `Subscript` keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>) for the ones without a `TagBox` and will look (together with their output) like

[image: Test1]

The output of the first test example nicely shows the correct parenthesization.

Finally the placeholder functions are defined as

```
myPlus = Plus;
myMinus[a_, b_] := Plus[a, Times[-1, b]]
myTimes[a_, b_] := Times[a, b]
myDivision = Divide;
```

and the examples tested again

```
\!\(\(9 \*TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"],Minus,SyntaxForm->"a"] 2 \*SubscriptBox[\(*\), \(i\)]3\)\*SubscriptBox[\(+\), \(i\)]\(4 \*SubscriptBox[\(/\), \(i\)]2\)\)

\!\(4\*SubscriptBox[\(+\), \(i\)]\(6\*SubscriptBox[\(*\), \(i\)]2    \*SubscriptBox[\(/\), \(i\)]4\)\)

\!\(\((9 \*TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"],Minus,SyntaxForm->"a"] 2    \*SubscriptBox[\(*\), \(i\)]3)\)\*SubscriptBox[\(+\), \(i\)]\(4    \*SubscriptBox[\(/\), \(i\)]2\)\)
```

[image: Test2]

As described in the tutorials linked to at the beginning of this answer, the [`SyntaxForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxForm.html) option of [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox.html) can be used to change the precedence of an operator. For the given examples this is only needed for $-_i$, because for the other operators it is determined by their corresponding operators without a subscript. For $-_i$ the precedence has to be changed, because otherwise everything following $-_i$ is parenthesized as one part. Using `SyntaxForm -> "a"` the precedence behavior is "group as a symbol".

Just to illustrate the wrong parenthesization, when the precedence behavior is "group as infix minus operator":

```
ClearAll[myPlus, myPlus, myDivision, myMinus]
RemoveInfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
  TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"], Minus, SyntaxForm -> "a"]], myMinus]

InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
  TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"], Minus, SyntaxForm -> "a-b"]], myMinus]

\!\(9\*TagBox[SubscriptBox["-", "i"],Minus,SyntaxForm->"a-b"]\(2\*SubscriptBox[\(*\), \(i\)]3\)\*SubscriptBox[\(+\), \(i\)]\(4\*SubscriptBox[\(/\), \(i\)]2\)\)
```

[image: wrongParenthesization]