# How to add named characters to Mathematica 10 or later?

Tags: front-end, fonts, customization, character-encoding, named-characters

*Any news regarding this for Mathematica 12?*

---

It appears that native support for the [Klingon alphabet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1278/121) has been removed from version 10:

```
\[KlingonA]
```

> Syntax::tsntxi: "\"!(\[ KlingonA])\" is incomplete; more input is needed.!(\"\")"

(Curiously `"Klingon"` remains in the `$CharacterEncodings` list.)

As an exercise I wish to restore support of this character set but the underlying character system has been modified; specifically I cannot find the `UnicodeFontMapping.tr` file and I assume it no longer exists.  Quoting `TechnicalNotes.nb` found in the `Prerelease` folder:

> On all systems, the Mathematica family of fonts (Mathematica*1-7) has
>   been replaced with a single Mathematica font.
>
> On Windows, the single Mathematica font is no longer installed under
>   "c:\windows\fonts". Instead, the user interface loads the font from
>   the installation directory.
>
> For prerelease testing, we are interested in learning about any issues
>   related to this change.

`UnicodeCharacters.tr` does remain (path given by `` System`Dump`unicodeCharactersTR ``) and the format appears unchanged so I should be able to restore recognition of `\[KlingonA]` etc., but without being able to map these characters to font glyphs that is largely pointless.  (Though it would correct unrecognized syntax in legacy code.)

**How can one create named characters and bind them to specific glyphs in v10 or v11?**

Comment: I wrote to Wolfram Support. When/If I get anything back  , I'll post it here.

Comment: There's a FontMap.Tr file under FrontEnd/TextResources directory, which contains compressed data. If I import it I get ... {"MathematicaFont" -> {33, 35, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, ... Did it exist in _9_ ?

Comment: @Zet Thanks for writing Support; I'll be interested in what they say.  Good observation about `FontMap.tr`; I believe I found that myself before writing this Question but was put off by the compression.  Since no one else has answered I'll see if I can hack this myself.  Thanks for the reminder. :-)

Comment: @Zet I remember now what stopped me with `FontMap.tr`.  I did `Uncompress` that data but the different sections don't appear to point to actual font files but rather internal classifications.  There is no "MathematicaFont" or "Diacritical" font file that I can see.  Experimenting today by adding a section with the name of an installed font does not seem to work.

Comment: I got a first response: "This is indeed an issue of our font system. Unfortunately we don't have a workaround at this moment. I've already forwarded your message to the development team and an incidence report has been opened on this issue.". I will keep this post updated.

Comment: @Zet Any updates?

Comment: Unfortunately @Mr.Wizard no response from support. I will send them an email to ask if there's any progress (I doubt there is). In the meantime I solved my own issues with M10 with the answer from DBM http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32684/how-to-write-plain-greek-in-a-text-cell

Answer (score 6):

**This is *not* a complete answer.**  However, since no other reply is forthcoming here are the lines that may be appended to `UnicodeCharacters.tr` as mentioned in the question.  This at least allows these characters to be recognized by the Front End rather than producing a syntax error.  **The glyphs remain broken.**

```
0xF8D0      \[KlingonA]     ()      Letter
0xF8D1      \[KlingonB]     ()      Letter
0xF8D2      \[KlingonCH]        ()      Letter
0xF8D3      \[KlingonD]     ()      Letter
0xF8D4      \[KlingonE]     ()      Letter
0xF8D5      \[KlingonGH]        ()      Letter
0xF8D6      \[KlingonH]     ()      Letter
0xF8D7      \[KlingonI]     ()      Letter
0xF8D8      \[KlingonJ]     ()      Letter
0xF8D9      \[KlingonL]     ()      Letter
0xF8DA      \[KlingonM]     ()      Letter
0xF8DB      \[KlingonN]     ()      Letter
0xF8DC      \[KlingonNG]        ()      Letter
0xF8DD      \[KlingonO]     ()      Letter
0xF8DE      \[KlingonP]     ()      Letter
0xF8DF      \[KlingonQ]     ()      Letter
0xF8E0      \[KlingonQH]        ()      Letter
0xF8E1      \[KlingonR]     ()      Letter
0xF8E2      \[KlingonS]     ()      Letter
0xF8E3      \[KlingonT]     ()      Letter
0xF8E4      \[KlingonTLH]       ()      Letter
0xF8E5      \[KlingonU]     ()      Letter
0xF8E6      \[KlingonV]     ()      Letter
0xF8E7      \[KlingonW]     ()      Letter
0xF8E8      \[KlingonY]     ()      Letter
0xF8E9      \[KlingonGlottalStop]       ()      Letter
0xF8F0      \[Klingon0]     ()      Letter
0xF8F1      \[Klingon1]     ()      Letter
0xF8F2      \[Klingon2]     ()      Letter
0xF8F3      \[Klingon3]     ()      Letter
0xF8F4      \[Klingon4]     ()      Letter
0xF8F5      \[Klingon5]     ()      Letter
0xF8F6      \[Klingon6]     ()      Letter
0xF8F7      \[Klingon7]     ()      Letter
0xF8F8      \[Klingon8]     ()      Letter
0xF8F9      \[Klingon9]     ()      Letter
0xF8FF      \[KlingonEmpire]        ()      Letter
```

Comment: Not sure how useful is that, but I have found a Mathematica file pertaining to Klingon in "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles CharacterEncodings" folder from under Ubuntu.

Comment: @Alexey I actually hadn't thought about that file.  I don't know if it will be of help or not yet, but thanks for reminding me of it!