# Mapping with Trace[]

Tags: functional-style

As part of some data anaylsis, I am using the function Trace to give me the name of an array of data, which I then use to label my plots.

eg. my data array is called r1 so I run:

```
ToString@((Trace[r1])[[1]])
```

which simply returns the string "r1".

All fine and dandy.

The problem arises when I try to do this for a list of data arrays, I write:

```
Trace[#]&/@{r1,r2}
```

which I expect to give me the list {"r1","r2"}. Instead I get {{},{}}.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: @Öskå
At the moment, r1 and r2 are both arrays with dimensions {1200,6}.

Comment: `{r1, r2}` is evaluated first, so the symbols are replaced by their values before `Trace` sees them.

Comment: In other words try `Trace[#][[1]] & /@ {Unevaluated@r1, Unevaluated@r2}`

Comment: @Öskå This works, thanks a lot.

(I'm not sure the etiquette here for asking follow-up but related questions).

Is there a way to prevent r1, r2 from being evaluated where I still pass the list {r1,r2} (as opposed to) {Unevaluated@r1, Unevaluated@r2}?
I assumed something like:

    Trace[#][[1]]&/@(Unevaluated/@{r1,r2})

might work, but it still seems to be evaluating the list {r1,r2} first.

Comment: Related by example: [(55531)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55531)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that's brilliant, thanks. I wish I'd found that example earlier. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Mapping Trace[]

Since `List` evaluates its arguments, the construct

```
Trace /@ { stuff }
```

will usually give you empty lists because the `stuff` has been evaluated before `Trace` sees it (and *Mathematica* is smart enough not to re-evaluate expressions which haven't changed). There is no more evaluation to be done, so `Trace` shows nothing.

### Solving the actual problem

Personally I would not use `Trace` for this purpose. You could instead define a function to extract symbol names using [`SymbolName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SymbolName.html):

```
SetAttributes[name, {Listable, HoldFirst}]; 
name[x_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated @ x]
```

I've made `name` `Listable` so that it automatically threads over lists.

E.g.

```
r1 = {1, 2, 3};
r2 = {2, 4, 6};

name[r1]
(*  "r1"  *)

name[{r1, r2}]
(*  {"r1", "r2"}  *)
```