# Generating compiled functions from inactive expressions

Tags: compile, hold

I am working on a project in which I need to dynamically generate `CompiledFunction`s from `Inactive` expressions. For example, I might be given something like

```
expr = Inactivate[Block[{x = ConstantArray[0.0, 100]},
    Do[x[[n]] = Sin[n/Pi]*Cos[y + n/100], {n, 100}];
    x]];
```

from which I need to generate the `CompiledFunction` given by

```
Compile[{y}, Block[{x = ConstantArray[0.0, 100]},
    Do[x[[n]] = Sin[n/Pi]*Cos[y + n/100], {n, 100}];
    x]];
```

The first thing I tried was simply `Compile[{y}, Evaluate@Activate@expr]`, but this is no good; it actually evaluates the `Block` prior to compilation, and gives me a `CompiledFunction` which computes each array element separately.

For my project, **it is crucial that the loop assigning to the array `x` be compiled,** and I cannot figure out the right combination of `Evaluate`, `Activate`, `Hold`, etc. that will give me what I want. How can I take `expr` and generate the `CompiledFunction` given above?

P.S. I've noticed that `ConstantArray[]` doesn't seem to be compilable. Is there a faster way to declare an empty array in compiled functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use good old `Hold` in place of `Inactivate`:

```
expr = 
   Hold[Block[{x = ConstantArray[0.0, 100]},
     Do[x[[n]] = Sin[n/Pi]*Cos[y + n/100], {n, 100}];
     x]];
```

then you can do simply use

```
expr /. Hold[code_] :> Compile @@ Hold[{y}, code]
```

which is, using [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937).

Comment: My apologies, but I appear to have spoken too soon. The code you've given above doesn't work for me; the problem is that `Compile` doesn't localize the `y` from `expr`, and using `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` doesn't help.

Comment: @DavidZhang Indeed. That's what happens when comment is directly transferred into an answer. I assumed that you tested it and it worked for you, but I should've tested myself. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks much. Can you explain why this second version works but the first didn't? I am rather puzzled as to why `y` wasn't localized.

Comment: @DavidZhang Read [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia), and references therein. Thanks for the accept. You may want to change your mind though, if some good answer involving `(In)Activate` arrives later.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is worth noting (if only for the benefit of future readers) that my original `expr` using `Inactive` can easily be transformed into your version using `Hold`; simply use `Activate@Hold@Evaluate@expr`.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work:

```
cf = Block[{n, x, y}, Inactive[Compile][{y}, expr] // Activate]
```

**Edit - Some observations**

`Inactivate` effectively blocks evaluation of heads in an expression by wrapping them with `Inactive`.  It does not hold or otherwise protect other symbols from being evaluated.  This was inconvenient above, and I used `Block` to protect `n`, `x` and  `y` in case they had been assigned values.

There are ways to take advantage of this, but they may just as easily bite you. The inactive piece of code `expr` may contain parameters which can be substituted at compile time.  For example, take the following modification of the OP's code:

```
expr = Inactivate[
  Block[{x = ConstantArray[0.0, max]}, 
   Do[x[[n]] = Sin[n/Pi]*Cos[y + n/max], {n, max}];
   x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `max`, `n`, `x`, and `y` are in black and in the inactive brown color.  If they had had values when `expr` was defined, the values would have been subsituted -- a disaster if, say, `x = 2`.  On the other hand, we can treat the code as a function of `max` and compile it at run time with whatever value of `max` we wish.

```
cf = Block[{max = 50, n, x, y}, Inactive[Compile][y, expr] // Activate];
```

We can examine the expression that was compiled:

```
cf[[-2]]
(*
  Function[{y}, 
   Block[{x = ConstantArray[0., 50]}, 
    Do[x[[n]] = Sin[n/π] Cos[y + n/50], {n, 50}]; x]]
*)
```

While it can be done, you have to block all the variables in `expr`.  Using `Hold` as Leonid shows seems preferable.  A judicious application of replacement before compiling, i.e., `Compile @@ (Hold[{y}, code] /. max -> 50)`, reproduces my second example above.  It has the advantage of not needing to know what variables are used in the code represented by `expr`.

Comment: Too bad that `Inactive[f]` does not inherit the attributes of `f`.  For example `HoldAll`.

Comment: If there was a way to attach attributes to a compound head like `Inactive[f]` we would have simplified solutions for http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/121 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54762/121 as well