# What is the difference between Composition (@*) and sequential applications (@)?

Tags: syntax, functional-style

What is the difference between

```
f@*g@*h@x
```

and

```
f@g@h@x
```

Both evaluate to

```
f[g[h[x]]]
```

If they're the same, why introduce `Composition` as a new feature?

Comment: Related: [(54762)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54762/121)

Comment: Observe the difference between `h = f @ g; h[x]` and `h = f @* g; h[x]`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Clearly the `@` notation is inspired by the usual mathematical notation for function composition.  `f@g[x]` *looks* very similar to the mathematical notation $(f\circ g)(x)$.  But it is important to understand that `@` does not denote function composition.  In mathematical notation $f\circ g$ is also a function.   In *Mathematica* `f@x` is simply a different way to write `f[x]`, but `f@g` is not (generally) a function.  Both `f@x` and `f[x]` parse to the exact same *Mathematica* expression.

So what is the true equivalent of $f \circ g$?  It is `Composition[f, g]` which can be more concisely written as `f @* g` since version 10, and can be used in situations where we need a function without applying it to an argument (e.g. with `Map`, or as an operator with `Dataset`).

---

Both of your examples evaluate to the very same things in the end, so they behave equivalently in this case.  But the way *Mathematica* arrives to the same end result is different:

`f@g@h@x` parses to an expression with the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html) `f[g[h[x]]]`, which doesn't evaluate further. There's no evaluation step.

`f@*g@*h@x` parses to an expression with the full form `Composition[f,g,h][x]`, which then evaluates to `f[g[h[x]]]`.

---

It's also worth pointing out that `@` and `@*` have different [precedences](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) and associativity properties as operators.  `f@g@x` is equivalent to `f@(g@x)` and `f@*g@x` is equivalent to `(f@*g)@x`.  Writing `...[...]` has a different precedence again so `f@*g[x]` is the same as `f@*(g[x])` (i.e. it's not the same as `f@*g@x`).

Comment: Could you say a bit more about the different meanings?

Comment: I think it is that last construct, `Composition[f,g]`, that is the most useful as you can easily pass around the composed function without having to craft it by hand.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, the big difference is that `f @ g` is the same as `f[g]`, while `f @* g` is roughly equivalent to `f[g[#]] &`.  For example of usage, `StringLength @* ToString /@ Range[10]` works whereas `StringLength @ ToString /@ Range[10]` does not.

Comment: @2012rcampion I would be cautious with the use of "*equivalent*".  `f @* g` is not the same as `f[g[#]]&`.  It is equivalent to `Composition[f,g]`.  In the sense that either `f @* g` or `Composition[f,g]` are interpreted as the very same expression during parsing.  It happens to be that `f[g[#]] &` works the same way as `Composition[f,g]`, but they are very different expressions.  (And of course, `f[g[#]] &` doesn't work *exactly* the same way, there are several subtle details that show in special edge cases.  Plus `Composition` used to unpack packed arrays pre-version-10...)

Comment: That's why I added "roughly equivalent." and changed the first "equivalent" to "is the same," to make clear the differences.  But if you don't know the details about `Composition` it gets the point of what it does across.

Comment: @2012rcampion Sorry, somehow I didn't see "roughly" ...

Comment: @Szabolcs It was a late edit... for some reason I keep waiting until right before the five-minute deadline to proofread my comments

Comment: I'm not as smart as I pretend to be, and I don't quite get the difference. So it would help me if it could be spelled out a bit. I see that they are different, but could you go into a bit more detail about exactly hat differs?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Do you understand what [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) means, and in the context of Mathematica do you understand the difference between parsing and evaluation?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes (enough, anyway). Maybe a more side-by-side presentation of the differences would do it for me.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius So is it clear then how `f@*g@x` and `f@g@x` simply parse to different expressions, which then are evaluated to the same?  Try wrapping both in `FullForm@Hold[...]` to prevent evaluation and see them written using the same notation.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes. I guess *how* they differ in some practical examples might be illuminating.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius They do work the same way most of the time.  Feel free to use either.  `@*` is more useful e.g. here: `Map[f@*g, ..., {2}]` or in any situation where you need a *function* but do not need to apply it to anything.  There's also the fact that `(f@*g)[x]` requires parentheses unlike `f@g[x]` or `f@*g@x`, so in the situation you describe `f@*g` seems more cumbersome and error prone when modifying code ...

Comment: @Szabolcs: So is it fair to say that the (or at least a) key conceptual distinction is that `@*` *creates a function* (which is not what `@` does)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It's funny (and I expect surprising, and maybe a bit frustrating to people who really understand something) what simple things can unlock understanding. Could you add something explicit abut "creating a function" in contrast to what `@` does to your answer (maybe with an example)? It would make a great answer even better. Thx.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You're right, I wasn't very good at explaining this ... that's why I resorted to asking questions in the comments instead.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It's a great explanation — I was just missing something pretty basic.

Comment: Really great answer (and greatly improved). Thanks. A follow up: `...[...]` and `...@...` have different precedence?

Comment: Any clue as to why `@*` was chosen over `∘` and why `\[SmallCircle]` is not even available as an undefined operator?

Answer (score 20):

> ... why introduce Composition as a new feature?

Composition is used to create a new anonymous function that can be used in all the standard ways such as `Map` and `Apply` etc.  To achieve the same thing without it one needs a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).  Much like [operator forms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121) the use of `Composition` allows one to eliminate extraneous `Function` constructs which can make code more linear and easier to read.  The short form `@*` and its companion `/*` (see [`RightComposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html)) make its application pleasingly concise.

`Composition` is not typically used for a single application but instead when one wishes to perform an operation multiple times.  Here are some related form:

```
f@*g@*h /@ {x, y, z}
f@g@h@# & /@ {x, y, z}
f /@ g /@ h /@ {x, y, z}
```

Each of these evaluate the same way in this particular case but there are differences that are not immediately apparent.  We can see some of them if we define:

```
f = HoldForm; g = Print; h = Sqrt;
```

Now:

```
f@*g@*h /@ {x, y, z}
f@g@h@# & /@ {x, y, z}
f /@ g /@ h /@ {x, y, z}
```

[image]

Because `Composition` does not hold its arguments the Symbols `g` and `h` are resolved to `Print` and `Sqrt` in the output from the first line.  In the second line `f` resolves first to `HoldForm` and as a result `g` and `h` remain verbatim.  Finally in the last line each function application is evaluated sequentially therefore the `Print` fires and `Null` is returned as the actual output.

See also:

- [Why doesn't a Composition[] hold its arguments and what can be done about it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54762/121)

Comment: Done.  +1 for the trouble, and for the quality answer.