# How to use Composition when the functions have two parameter

Tags: function-construction, syntax, built-in-symbols

There are some [basic instructions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78982/21532) about `Composition` on this site, but I'm still confused on how to use it when the functions I am composing have two parameter, such as:

```
t := RandomImage[1, {50, 50}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
picList = Array[t &, 3];
ImageResize[#, 500] &@*ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] & /@ picList
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when the composition functions just have one parameter, the behavior is more predictable:

```
hh@*ff /@ picList
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can anybody explain this strange behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` has a very low [operator precedence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html), in particular it's lower than `@*`'s precedence. That means that the right-hand `&` is actually defining an unnamed function with the body:

```
ImageResize[#, 500] & @* ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"]
```

You can fix this by wrapping the right-hand function in parentheses:

```
ImageResize[#, 500] & @* (ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &) /@ piclist
```

Or both of them for consistency:

```
(ImageResize[#, 500] &) @* (ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &) /@ piclist
```

Of course, as you mentioned in a comment, that doesn't help much compared with

```
(ImageResize[#, 500] &) /@ (ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &) /@ piclist
```

If you want to avoid the parentheses altogether, you could still define a pure function via the `Function`, but of course, that's even less terse, and technically you've just replaced parentheses with square brackets:

```
Function[ImageResize[#, 500]] @* Function[ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"]] /@ piclist
```

You can also use the full form of `@*` instead:

```
Composition[ImageResize[#, 500] &, ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &] /@ piclist
```

Alternatively, you could apply both transformations in a single function:

```
ImageResize[ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"], 500] & /@ piclist
```

Or use infix notation for a nicer reading order:

```
# ~ColorConvert~ "Grayscale" ~ImageResize~ 500 & /@ piclist
```

Comment: Applaud for the last form :)

Comment: Or we can use `Composition[ImageResize[#,500]&,ColorConvert[#,"Grayscale"]&]/@picList` to aviod the bracket

Comment: @yode Oh, good point, I'll add that for completeness.

Comment: For something this elaborate, I'd go with the penultimate snippet. Not worth having to try to look up precedence just to have compact code.