# Return unevaluated expression from function

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Is there any way (except using upvalues) to make a function that returns it's input `Unevaluated`?  What I mean by that:

Take the following example:

```
Apply[foo]@Unevaluated[Print@1]
(* foo[1] *)

(* this function should only "look" at x, but not affect anything else *)
tee[x_] := (Echo@HoldForm@x; Unevaluated@x)

Apply[foo]@*tee@Unevaluated[Print@1]
(* 1 *)    
(* Null *)   

(* not exactly the case I need this for,
   but demonstrates that the issue is not only with Composition *)
Apply[foo]@tee@Unevaluated[Print@1]
(* Print[1] *)    
(* Null *)
```

The goal is to have the last line behave exactly the same way as the first one (except for the `Echo` of course). Like I mentioned above, this could probably be done using upvalues, but it feels like there has to be a simpler solution that I'm just not seeing...

Or in other words (in case the above is not clear): How to define a function (`tee`) with the following properties:

- Can be composed (`@*`) with any non-`Hold*` function (i.e. without any `Hold*` attribute) without leaking evaluation
- Should be fully transparent: If the argument is `Unevaluated` pass it along as such, otherwise don't prevent evaluation
- Should work with any number of arguments (e.g. `(foo@*tee)[a,b]`)

#### Update

I seem to have failed state my needs clearly - I am only interested in preserving arguments wrapped in `Unevaluated`, not in keeping `Hold*` attributes while using `@*`.

Comment: looks like closely related: [Why doesn't a Composition hold its arguments and what can be done about it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54762/5478) and related: [78979](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78979/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the links, but I don't think they're that closely related - I'm interested in the cases where one explicitly wraps arguments in `Unevaluated` (which prevents works together with `Composition`, e.g. `(a@*Hold)[Unevaluated@Print@1]`). I will try to make the question a bit clearer in that regard.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit. I will leave those links for interested readers anyway.

Comment: What if you change all `Unevaluated` to `Inactivate`?

Comment: Try `SetAttributes[tee, HoldAllComplete]; tee[x_] := (Echo @ HoldForm @ x; Unevaluated[Unevaluated][Unevaluated[x]])`

Comment: @swish: That changes the input though (what I mean is that now `Inactive[Print][x]` is returned instead of `Print[x]` in an unevaluated form)

Comment: @J.M. thanks for the idea, but unfortunately this doesn't work - the returned expression stays `Unevaluated[Unevaluated][Unevaluated[Print[x]]]` forever...

Comment: I have the feeling that `Unevaluated` is not meant for what you are using it. I would also suggest to use `Inactive` in combination with `Activate`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The issue with that is that I need control over the function handling the return value of my function, which I do not have, so the solution needs to be self-contained

Comment: `Unevaluated` is was never meant to be a stable wrapper that can be returned from a function. You probably can sometimes do this, but I really can't encourage trying to actually do this in practice. It's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>For anyone coming across this, an answer in the above comments (from J. M.'s ennui) worked for me with minor modifications.  All credit goes to him; I'd have never guessed that you'd need two "helpings" of `Unevaluated[...]` to achieve the effect of returning an unevaluated expression from a function!  Maybe it has to do with the function *call* itself using Compose, causing one "round" of `Unevaluated` to be "used up"??? Speculating here...</strike>

EDIT: `UnevaluatedDouble[2]` actually did not work for me; trying to use the result downstream results in `Unevaluated` persisting forever.  See links below.

```
UnevaluatedSingle[x_] := Unevaluated[x + 1]
UnevaluatedDouble[x_] := Unevaluated@Unevaluated[x + 1]
UnevaluatedSingle[2]
UnevaluatedDouble[2]
```

Results:

```
3
Unevaluated[2 + 1]
```

However, per a post I'll link to in a second, apparently "`Unevaluated` is not meant to be a function or stable data type."  So although I've found some cases where the above trick was useful for me (at least prima facie), I'm not certain whether its use in this manner is ever "supported" or not.

As to the OP's original question... per this post:

[Unexpected behavior of Unevaluated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25266/76328)

I'll quote a small excerpt from Mr. Wizard, who in turn quotes a [presentation](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/) by Robby Villegas:

> Unevaluated must be wrapper before argument evaluation, not after, else it isn't stripped.
>
> ...
>
> Unevaluated is not meant to be a function or stable data type. It is to be used as a wrapper on an argument in stage 1, before argument evaluation.

Therefore, unless I'm missing something, the OP's question can't be solved quite as suggested, directly, e.g. via:

```
tee[x_] := (Echo@HoldForm@x; Unevaluated@Unevaluated@x)
```

... because you can't actually *return* an expression whose *head* is `Unevaluated` -- it's never meant to be the head of an expression.  Instead, one solution would be to make a form of `tee` where the call-site passes-in the function to be called and/or the "auxiliary" function (e.g. `Echo`) to `tee`.

Version 1:

```
ClearAll[tee]
SetAttributes[tee, HoldAll]
tee[expr_, mainFunc_, auxFunc_ : Echo@*HoldForm] := (auxFunc@Unevaluated@expr; mainFunc@Unevaluated@expr)
tee[Print@3, Apply[foo]]
```

The following two versions were written to illustrate the syntax difference required when using composition (which was called-out by the OP):

Version 2a

```
ClearAll[tee]
SetAttributes[tee, HoldAll]
tee[expr_, mainFunc_, 
  auxFunc_ : Function[e, Echo@HoldForm@e, HoldAll]]
  := (auxFunc@expr; mainFunc@expr)
tee[Print@3, Function[e, foo @@ Unevaluated@e, HoldAll]]
```

Version 2b

```
ClearAll[tee]
SetAttributes[tee, HoldAll]
tee[expr_, mainFunc_, auxFunc_ : 
   Function[e, Echo@*HoldForm@Unevaluated@e, HoldAll]]
   := (auxFunc@expr; mainFunc@expr)
tee[Print@3, Function[e, foo @@ Unevaluated@e, HoldAll]]
```

Depending on what the "real" application of this was, and your taste in syntax, the below is a final alternative:

```
ClearAll[tee]
SetAttributes[tee, HoldAll]
tee[expr_, auxFunc_ : Echo@*HoldForm]
   := (auxFunc@Unevaluated@expr; #[Unevaluated@expr] &)
tee[Print@3][Apply[foo]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write your own `Unevaluated`-like wrapper using just up-values with slightly different behavior. I called it [`Held`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/ArgumentTools/ref/Held.html), and it's a part of this small weird [ArgumentTools](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/ArgumentTools/) paclet now. It is almost like `Unevaluated`, but doesn't have weird internal semantics. And I hadn't even considered that it could be used for this scenario until I stumbled upon this question :).

In your example, the `tee` should just return an expression wrapped with `Held` (you can install the paclet and use the symbol directly, of course):

```
tee[x_] := (
  Echo[HoldForm[x]];
  PacletSymbol["Wolfram/ArgumentTools", "Wolfram`ArgumentTools`Held"] @@ Hold[x]
  )
```

I use `Held @@ Hold[x]`, because `Held` disappears from any holding argument position (except it's `HoldAllComplete`), which is `CompoundExpression` in this case:

```
Hold[Held[x]] === Hold[x]
HoldComplete[Held[x]] === HoldComplete[Held[x]]
```

And now, your second example would work as it is:

```
Apply[foo] @ tee @ Unevaluated[Print@1]
(* foo[1] *)
```

The thing with `Composition` (@*), though, is that it also absorbs one `Unevaluated` before passing its argument to `tee`, so you need to wrap it twice:

```
Apply[foo] @* tee @ Unevaluated[Unevaluated@Print@1]
(* foo[1] *)
```

`Held` would also work as an outer wrapper here, but not the inner one, because it flattens itself into `Unevaluated`:

```
foo[Held[Held[Held@Print@1]]]
(* foo[Unevaluated[Print[1]]] *)
```

So `Held` and `Unevaluated` really complement each other nicely.