# Is Sow/Reap compatible with Composition?

Tags: function-construction, sow-reap

I'm trying to figure out why these two pieces of code return different results. As expected,

```
f[Reap[Sow[x]]]
```

gives `f[{x,{{x}}}]` as output, but

```
fReap = f @* Reap;
fReap[Sow[x]]
```

gives `f[{x,{}}]`. According to my understanding of the composition operator `@*`, the expressions

```
h = f @* g; h[x]
```

and

```
f[g[x]]
```

should give the same result. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Reap` has the attribute `HoldAll`.  This is necessary so that its argument is not evaluated until `Reap` has set up the conditions necessary to capture the values designated by `Sow`.  The implementation of `@*` (`Composition`) is such that it interferes with the attributes of the right-most composed function.  In the exhibited example, the `Sow` expression is evaluated prematurely because `Composition` interferes with the `HoldAll` attribute on `Reap`.

**Analysis**

This behaviour will effect any function with attributes, not just `Reap`.  The following examples show how `Composition` effectively strips the `HoldAll` attribute off of `Hold`...

```
f @ Hold[1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[1 + 1]] *)

(f @* Hold)[1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[2]] *)

Composition[f, Hold][1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[2]] *)
```

... and here is an example showing `SequenceHold` being ignored:

```
SetAttributes[ss, SequenceHold]

Defer @ ss[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
(* ss[Sequence[1, 2, 3]] *)

(Defer @* ss)[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
(* ss[1, 2, 3] *)
```

The problem is that `f @* Hold` is behaving as if it were implemented as `f @ Hold[##] &`:

```
f @ Hold[1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[1 + 1]] *)

Composition[f, Hold][1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[2]] *)

(f @ Hold[##] &)[1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[2]] *)
```

The expression `f @ Hold[##] &` is a pure function that has no attributes.  In particular, it does not have the `HoldAll` attribute.  Thus, it evaluates its argument before passing it on to the body of the function.  Just like `Composition`.  And, also like `Composition`, functions such as these preserve the attributes of all functions but the right-most:

```
ClearAll[ff, gg]
SetAttributes[{ff, gg}, HoldAll]
ff[x_] := Defer[22 + x]
gg[x_] := 11 + x

ff @ gg[1 + 1]
(* 22 + gg[1 + 1] *)

Composition[ff, gg][1 + 1]
(* 22 + gg[2] *)

(ff @ gg[##] &)[1 + 1]
(* 22 + gg[2] *)
```

On an incidental note, degenerate cases involving `Composition` actually *do* preserve function attributes. Consider:

```
Composition[Hold][1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)

Composition[Identity, Hold][1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)
```

Indeed, optimizations involving `Identity` sometimes go too far, getting the wrong answer:

```
Hold @ Identity[1 + 1]
(* Hold[Identity[1 + 1]] *)

Composition[Hold, Identity][1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)
```

But we digress.  To work around the main problems under discussion, we can implement our own composition using a `Function` with appropriate attributes.  For example, we can preserve `HoldAll` like this:

```
Function[Null, f @ Hold[##], HoldAll][1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[1 + 1]] *)
```

**General Workaround**

We could also define our own general composition operator that makes a pretty good attempt at preserving attributes:

```
comp[f___] :=
  Module[{h}
  , SetAttributes[h, HoldAll]
  ; ReplacePart[
      Function[Null, Null, HoldAllComplete]
    , h[f, ##] //. h[a___, b_, c_] :> h[a, b@c]
    , 2
    , 1
    ]
  ]
```

This attempt is not fool-proof, but in practice it is usually good enough (and better than `Composition`):

```
comp[f, Hold]
(* Function[Null, f[Hold[##1]], HoldAllComplete] *)

comp[f, Hold][1 + 1]
(* f[Hold[1 + 1]] *)

comp[Defer, ss][Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
(* ss[Sequence[1, 2, 3]] *)

comp[ff, gg][1 + 1]
(* 22 + gg[1 + 1] *)

comp[Hold][1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)

comp[Identity, Hold][1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)

comp[Hold, Identity][1 + 1]
(* Hold[Identity[1 + 1]] *)
```

It would be better if `Composition` were built into the *Mathematica* kernel in such fashion as to respect attributes.  However, that would represent a breaking change to a long-standing language feature.

Comment: I've only just now realized that this behaviour in `Composition` is discussed at length in [(54762)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54762/142).