# How to create an equivalent of Clojure's threading macro in Mathematica?

Tags: programming

[Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure), a Lisp type of language, has a so called `Thread` macro which converts nested function calls into a linear flow of function calls, thus improving readability, testability and inviting pure functional (reactive) programming.

I suppose that an equivalent in *Mathematica* would work as follows:

Let

```
 listany = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; 
 listopr = {Flatten, Map[f], Map[g]};
```

and assume that `t` is the equivalent of Clojure's `->` ( thread macro ), and $f$ and $g$ are functions transforming elements of `listany`. Then:

```
 t[listany, listopr]
```

would be translated to

```
 Map[g]@Map[f]@Flatten@listany
```

Similarly,

```
 t[5, {f, g, h}]
```

would be translated to

```
 h@g@f@5
```

Do you have a suggestion on how to implement `t` in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Look at [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) or [`RightComposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html)

Comment: I knew it had to be somewhere in Mma. Suppose this works.

Comment: @niloderoock Would you consider penning a self-answer, perhaps exploring the use of those two newly discovered functions?

Comment: Be careful with `Composition`: try `x = 1; SymbolName@Unevaluated@x` vs `Composition[SymbolName, Unevaluated][x]` more in closely related: [**54762**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54762/5478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inefficiently your operation is performed by [`ComposeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComposeList.html):

```
ComposeList[listopr, listany] // Last
```

> ```
> {g[f[1]], g[f[2]], g[f[3]], g[f[4]]}
> ```

[`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

```
(Composition @@ Reverse @ listopr) @ listany
```

New-in-v10 [`RightComposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html)

```
(RightComposition @@ listopr) @ listany
```

The deprecated but reliable function [`Compose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compose.html) can also be applied with work:

```
Compose @@ Append[Reverse @ listopr, listany]
```

As Kuba comments these forms do not evaluate in the same way as the literal form.  If you wish to create the complete expression before evaluation consider `comp` from my self-answer to:

- [Why doesn't a Composition[] hold its arguments and what can be done about it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54762/why-doesnt-a-composition-hold-its-arguments-and-what-can-be-done-about-it/54769#54769)