# Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 7?

Tags: syntax, core-language, documentation, compatibility

There is documentation of the incompatible changes made to *Mathematica* with each major release:

- [Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html)

Unfortunately that documentation simply stopped with version 7.  Therefore I ask:

### What incompatible changes have been made since *Mathematica* 7?

There are [other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54606/different-colors-when-comparing-plot3d-v9-and-v10) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54481/121) on the subject but I wish to make this an exhaustive index for easy reference.

Comment: Somewhat related; my attempt to list fixable bugs by version: [(30599)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30599/121)

Comment: It seems this tutorial has been updated through version 12.1 now.

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks!  I am glad; this Q&A should not have been needed, as the developers are in a far better position to write such a thing.  Nevertheless please let me know if important points here are missing from the official one.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

#### Prelude

The items in this post are not generally regressions; they are simply *changes* and enhancements that may break code or cause problems in moving from one version to another.  The work-arounds are offered as specific solutions to instances of incompatibility, *not* as recommendations of general practice.  For example, Plot Themes are a [powerful tool](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4716/121) one should learn to use; I discourage disabling this tool by setting `$PlotTheme = None` unless that is needed for a *specific* result.

---

## Between Versions 11.3 and 12.0

- Functions in the built-in `` "MediaTools`" `` package allowing fast import of AVI files frame-by-frame were [renamed and received usage documentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204875/280).
- [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) no longer sums over arbitrary heads by default.  Use option `AllowedHeads -> Inherited` for the old behavior, or `AllowedHeads -> All` to sum over mixed heads. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198869/121))

#### LibraryLink

- `WolframLibraryVersion` bumped to `5` (from `4`)

---

## Between Versions 11.2 and 11.3

- `ShowGroupOpener` behavior: [ShowGroupOpener's behavior change in 11.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171236/5478)
- `FindFaces` syntax: [FindFaces in Mathematica 11.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171895/5478)
- `Hash`

  - for strings it calculates hash of bytes of utf8 representation of a string. So to achieve new behaviour in old versions you can use: `Hash[ToString["¥", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]]` to get old result in 11.3 you can use `` Developer`LegacyHash ``.
  - Additionally it treats `ByteArray` as a raw list of bytes now

  - [HMAC correct on 11.2 but wrong and different on 11.3 running same code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167633/5478)
  - [How does Hash calculate hash for strings?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160589/5478)
- **[`ImageCompose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCompose.html)** received a long-waiting fix: [now it has the associative property again](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60048/280) and for the first time produces correct results according to the [classical Duff-Porter definitions](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1212695) (at least for the default Duff-Porter "over" compositing operation).
- [`"CatchMachineUnderflow"` option is removed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174474/1871), *Mathematica* no longer switches to arbitrary precision automatically; it underflows to subnormal floating-point numbers or to zero. Old numerical code might result in different behavior. A few examples: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170416/2036), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181165/1871),
  [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174587/why-this-weird-return-value-from-n),
  [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94996/machine-precision-near-zero-not-fulfilled)

#### LibraryLink

- `MSparseArray_getExplicitValues()` now returns `NULL` when called with a non-pattern sparse array that has no explicit values stored. Previously, it would return a valid but empty `MTensor`. It would only return `NULL` when called on a pattern array.

---

## Between Versions 11.1 and 11.2

- [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) now returns an `Image` instead of `Graphics` by default. Use the second argument to specify what format to return.
- `<->` and `TwoWayRule` introduction

  `<->` was parsed as `\[UndirectedEdge]`, now (11.2+) as `\[TwoWayRule]`. `TwoWayRule` is interpreted by `Graph` functions as `UndirectedEdge` but that does not solve the problem: [158657](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158657/5478)
- **`` LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber ``** is no longer present in 11.2 and [several Q&A depend on it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MatrixConditionNumber); one can use `` LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber `` instead.

#### LibraryLink

- `WolframLibraryVersion` bumped to `4` (from `3`)

---

## Between Versions 11.0 and 11.1

- [**`Image`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v11.1/ref/Image.html) Arithmetic and statistical operations such as `Log`, `Plus` and `Mean` work directly with `Image` since then e.g. `Image[{{1, 2}, {4, 5}}/10] == Image[{{1, 2}, {4, 5}}]/10` now returns `True`.

---

## Between Versions 10.4 and 11

- [**`PolyhedronData`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyhedronData.html) syntax changes

    [What has changed in PolyhedronData in V11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146769/5478)

---

## Between Versions 10 and 10.1

- In function definitions [default value neen not nesessarily match the pattern anymore](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108636/280).
- [**`FrameTicks`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) no longer recognizes the syntax **{*bottom*, *left*, *top*, *right*}**

    Give specifications in the form **{{*left*, *right*}, {*bottom*, *top*}}**

    Or redefine an internal function `FrameTicksQ`: [(82675)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82675/121)
- [**`MovingMap`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html) has seen major revision with incompatible syntax changes. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80092/121))

    Use the option `Method -> "Legacy"` within `MovingMap` to achieve the old behavior
- [**`Optional`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) behavior has changed in the case of incongruous head patterns. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108636/121))
- `ImageAdd` and `ImageMultiply` now by default always assume alpha channel for non-transparent single-channel images to be equal to `1`. In previous versions it was taken to be equal to the color channel. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156361/280))

---

## Between Versions 9 and 10

- [**`Join`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html) now allows `Join[{A[x]}, {A[x]}, 2]`: [Silent change (bug?) of Join after v9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184208/1871)
- [**`Slot`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html): in V10 `#x` and `#"x"` now parse as `Slot["x"]` and is interpreted as key name `x` for use with [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html).  In prior versions these were parsed as multiplication: `#1 * x` and `#1 * "x"`.

    Add something to act as a separator or use `#1` form: `# x`, `#*x`, `#1x`, `(#)x`
- [**`Dispatch`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) expressions are now Atomic and cannot be manipulated with `Part` or patterns.

    Use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html) to convert a `Dispatch` table into a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) list.
- [**`DateDifference`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateDifference.html) now returns a [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantity.html) expression.

    Use [`DayCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DayCount.html) instead or use [`QuantityMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html) to strip the units.

    Alternatively, using `SetSystemOptions["DataOptions" -> "ReturnQuantities" -> False]` will restore the old `DateDifference` behavior (see *Possible Issues* section of the `DateDifference` documentation).
- [**`DateRange`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateRange.html) now returns lists with year, month and day regardless of what the increment is.

    The change and possible workarounds are further discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57880/different-results-with-daterange-and-leapyearsq-in-mathematica-9-and-10/57884#57884).
- [**`GeoDistance`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeoDistance.html) and [**`GeoDirection`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeoDirection.html) now return a [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantity.html) expression.

    Use [`QuantityMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html) to strip out the units.
  (This solution applies to any function that now returns a `Quantity` instead of a value.)
- **[Klingon character support](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1278/121)** has been removed.  `\[KlingonA]` etc. are no longer recognized as valid input syntax. [Solution unknown.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54721/121)
- [**`LogPlot`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogPlot.html) and family no longer provide [standard log plot gridlines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54613/121) when `Automatic` is specified.

    A `GridLines` [function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60108/121) based on the internal Ticks generator may be used. ([broken in 10.0.0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54578/121))
- [**`PlotTheme`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotTheme.html) changes the fundamental style of most plots and overrides [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BaseStyle.html) and [`GraphicsBoxOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsBoxOptions.html) settings.

    Use `PlotTheme -> None`, individually or with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html) or [`$PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$PlotTheme.html).
- **`PlotLegends -> "Expressions"`** [does not generate a legend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56829/121) when used with a single plot function.

    Use `PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"` instead.
- [**`PlotLegends`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) now does not automatically generate more legend items than there are colors in the working color scheme. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66055/121))

    Use a [color scheme](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html) with a sufficient number of colors to differentiate all plot elements, a gradient scheme, or a manual legend specification.
- [**`ParallelNeeds`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelNeeds.html) defaults to the `System` context when loading packages which introduce symbols outside the package context.  In previous versions (and `Needs`) these symbols are in the `Global` context. This has been confirmed by Wolfram support as a design decision, not a bug.

    Create global symbols within package files in the `Global` context explicitly, as in `` Global`x ``.
- [**`NSolve`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) returns the same solution several times to indicate its multiplicity. Before V10 it returned a solution with multiplicity only once. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57479/731))

    Use `DeleteDuplicates@NSolve[...]`
- [**`Nearest`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) gives message and returns unevaluated when given an empty list as first argument. In Version 9 and before an empty list was returned.

    check for empty lists before calling `Nearest` or for unevaluated `Nearest` in result...
- [**`WeatherData`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeatherData.html) now returns a [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) object using [`TimeSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) and [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) rather than a plain array.

    Use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) and [`QuantityMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html) to recover the plain form for legacy code.
- [**`ListPlot`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) and [**`ListLinePlot`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) may use a wider `Automatic` plot range than expected when working with data that covers a very small range. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87808/121))

    Use the undocumented option `"AllowMicroRanges" -> True` for individual plots or set `` SetOptions[System`ProtoPlotDump`iListPlot, "AllowMicroRanges" -> True] ``.
- **`Blur`**, **`ImageConvolve`**, **`GaussianFilter`** now [aren't applied to the alpha channel of `Image`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156384/280) (what is consistent with behavior of `ImageAdjust`, `Dilation` etc.). `ImageFilter` and `ImageCorrelate` still affect the alpha channel. 
  To reproduce the old behavior one should [remove the colorspace information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156214/280).
- **`ImageCompose`** has [lost the associative property](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156283/280) and produces entirely different results than earlier. The [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156283/280) is to divide the color channel of the output by its alpha channel.

---

## Between Versions 8 and 9

- [**`Image`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image.html) expressions are now Atomic; data cannot be extracted using `Part`.

    Use [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageData.html) and [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Options.html) to extract raster data and options respectively.

    Use [`PixelValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PixelValue.html) or [`ImageValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageValue.html) to query raster values

    Replacement rules are overloaded to work: `Image[{{.1, .3, .9}}] /. _[x__] :> {x}`
- [**`Interpolation`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) of an unstructured grid is in V8 possible for more than 3 dimensions (linear interpolation only). In V9 and higher `Interpolation` in more than 3 dimensions is not possible. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59919/121)) 

    3rd party realizations of unstructured grid interpolations are available [here](http://portal.uni-freiburg.de/imteksimulation/downloads/ims), [here](http://www.familydahl.se/mathematica/), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31374/how-can-i-speed-up-my-compiled-function-that-is-returned-by-another-function), and [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-68017-8_9) ( using different approaches and with different performance).
- [**`TeXForm`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html) no longer works properly with [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html) expressions, whether by design or oversight. ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55363/121))

    Set `` BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow = False; ``
- [**`Solve`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) can now return [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) objects, rather then just one particular branch of the inverse.

    Use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html) to remove the `ConditionalExpression` head. This however does not remove any [`GeneratedParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeneratedParameters.html).

    Revert to version 8 behavior via [`SystemOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SystemOptions.html): `SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "UseTranscendentalSolve" -> False]`.
- [**General Legend functionality**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Legends.html) has been overhauled.  Many things do not work quite the same and many low-level methods no longer work. ([Example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4576/121))
- [**`PlotJoined`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotJoined.html) option for [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) is no longer accepted.  (It was deprecated in 6.0 but continued to work.)

    Use [`Joined`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Joined.html) in its place, or [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html).

---

## Between Versions 7 and 8

- [**`Hash`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hash.html) now gives the hash of a raw sequence of characters when applied to Strings.  In past versions the string characters (quotation marks) were included in the calculation of the hash.  ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13529/121))

    Use `"\"" <> string <> "\""` before hashing if you want output to match older versions.
- [**`\[Dash]`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Dash.html), [**`\[LongDash]`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/LongDash.html) and [**`\[Hyphen]`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Hyphen.html) may no longer be used as part of Symbol names.  ([Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31759/guidelines-on-giving-readable-names-to-variables/31761#comment98987_31761))
- [**`ImageCrop`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCrop.html) no longer removes layers of bordering pixels with color values that [**exactly match** the colors of the borders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20494/precise-cropping-with-imagecrop#comment62900_20494), now it "removes borders from image whose pixel value distribution is **almost uniform**."

  A [workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20495/280) is to use `ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img, 0]]` instead of `ImageCrop`.

---

---

## Non-version-specific

- [**`Hash`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hash.html) used without a specified *type* cannot be expected to return the same value from one version or platform to the next.  There appears to be no way to compute the `Hash` values from older versions apart from actually running that version of *Mathematica*.

    Specify a hash *type* if you intend to rely on the stability of these values.

Comment: Klingon character support has been removed: that's because Klingons do not respect the Galactic Copyright Treaty

Comment: Writing `#x` and `#"string"` in versions < 10 to mean `# x` and `# "string"` respectively is bad form anyway (a habit propagated by the Church of the Tersists, no doubt ;)). Such code deserves to be broken  :P

Comment: @rm-rf The interactive editor would previously auto-space such things just as it still does when you type `3x`.  (I don't mean that it enters a literal space but rather shows the expression with spacing.)  Do you always type a space between such things?  I have not as it seemed like wasted effort.

Comment: Yup, I almost always write a space for implicit `Times`. Probably started doing that because I used to (and still do) write in code cells or with non-interactive editors such as vim/IDEA.

Comment: @rm-rf Regarding your changing this post to CW, I suppose that is appropriate if this is to be the sole answer, but I actually did not intend that, though I failed to state my intentions in the Question.  I chose an **Issue: Solution:** format unlike the existing documentation, which is simply a bulleted list of changes with no comment on impact or work-arounds.  I thought others might have a different idea for how this information should be presented.  Do you feel that the format I chose is sufficiently universal to be the sole answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think we have (at least in the past) consistently been applying CW to anything that calls for a growing and collaborative "list of x" regardless of whether that list is presented as one post or many. It is a more recent phenomenon that such questions are not CW, but that seems more an oversight... I don't have a particular opinion on the format — I'm sure there are other equally useful formats that others might come up with. Your choice shouldn't prevent them from using theirs. I added my entry to yours in your format because I didn't think it warranted a new post.

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard - You might consider rcollyer's excellent answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56829/plotlegends-expressions-not-working-when-plot-given-one-function

Comment: @eldo Thanks; added.

Comment: I can't edit Mr. Wizard's answer, so he is welcome to add this to his list at his discretion.

In version 9, expressions evaluated in parallel default to the `Global` context. In version 10, expressions evaluated in parallel default to `System`.  This causes shadowing when using `ParallelNeeds` on packages which are supposed to define global symbols, and leaks symbols into the `System` context.

This has been confirmed by Wolfram support as a design decision, not a bug.

Comment: @Daniel This is a Community Wiki answer and it should only take 100 "reputation" to edit it.  Did you try?  And thanks for reporting this change.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for letting me know. I was not aware of circumstances where I could edit someone else's post. Also, it seemed presumptuous for me to edit your post.  Should I just copy/paste the comment into the post as it is?

Comment: @Daniel The edit looks good.  Thanks!

Comment: @eldo, I think the `Inset` thing is a bug rather than a deliberate change, so it doesn't belong in this list in my opinion.

Comment: @SimonWoods I agree, thanks and deleted :)

Comment: @DanielW Do you have a link to a discussion about this?

Comment: @Szabolcs The original report was filed online, I did not keep a copy.  Below is a copy of the reply from support:

Thanks for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. Regarding the issue you reported, it seems this is an intentional design change. We have internal discussions on this and the argument from the developer is that "Setting `$Context` to `$System` on subkernels is necessary to make sure (new) system symbols arrive in the correct context on subkernels, because despite the `MathLinkPrintFullSymbolName` settings, system symbols do not have their context attached".

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that the `InterpolationFunction` compatibility issue has been fixed in **v10.0.1** ?

Comment: @RunnyKine To begin with you should post that here: [(57608)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57608) Probably that item can be removed from this list as this post is not intended to catalog corrected bugs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is the difference with `Hash` in version 10? The documentation doesn't seem to show any important differences, but since I'm using Windows 2003 I don't have version 10 on this computer to verify it.

Comment: @Oleksandr Simply: the (default) hash value returned for a given expression in v10 does not match the (default) hash value from earlier versions.

Comment: Versions 7 and 8 give the same hash value, but in general, the other versions don't. I couldn't see any big differences in the overall magnitude or distribution of the values between 9 and 10, so I would say the algorithm is probably the same, but some internal detail has changed that leads to slightly different results. In general I think the constancy of hash values between versions is something we shouldn't rely on. The only important thing is that there should be no collisions.

Comment: @Oleksandr Interesting.  Do you know if all pre-version-8 `Hash` values were the same?  At this point it's clear we shouldn't rely on a constant (default) hash value, but it may have seemed like a reasonable expectation at some time in the past.

Comment: Version 8 and 9 differ; version 5.2 also differs from version 7. I don't have version 6 installed any more so I can't check that, but I wouldn't be surprised if it differs as well. The 32- and 64-bit kernels give the same value as each other in versions 7 and 8, but not in version 9. The magnitudes of the hashes in the 32- and 64-bit kernels of version 9 are also rather different (basically, the 64-bit version gives a 62-bit hash, but the 32-bit one gives 31 bits).

Comment: @Oleksandr Thanks.  I wasn't the one who added that item to this list so I hesitate to remove it entirely, but I think it needs to be amended with this information.

Comment: Countries in `CountryData[]` in *Mathematica* 10.1 are represented as an `Entity` while in versions 9.0 (and presumably earlier) they are not.

Comment: "returns the same solution several times to indicate its multiplicity" - I'd argue that this is actually an improvement.

Comment: @Guess Is there something in this post that seems to indicate otherwise?

Comment: Well, the suggestion of using `DeleteDuplicates[]` looks like throwing away useful information to me here, you see.

Comment: @Guess Ah, I think I understand the confusion.  The bulleted points are not meant as (general) suggestions but *specific* backward-compatibility patches.  The items in this answer are *not* to be seen as backslides or bugs; they are simply *changes* that may result in old code (or methods) not working as anticipated, and quick fixes when known.  Maybe something about this should be included in a **Prelude** section?

Comment: Ah, that's cool then. You can add a prelude, of course.

Comment: @Guess Please let me know if that is sufficiently clear and concise.

Comment: Yes, it's now good. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard was adding one example and ended up reversing the order :), I think it is more user friendly. Also, I've changed layout a little, let me know what do you think, but I can read when headers have the same indentation as items inside.

Comment: @Kuba I was following the order of the existing official documentation, but I don't have a strong opinion about it either way.  I suppose your order puts the information most people will be most interested in at the top.  The formatting looks good.  Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have version 10.0.1 installed on my machine (Win7 x64) and with it `img = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/UsJTa.png"];
ImageData[Blur[img, 5]] == ImageData[img]` returns `True`. That's why I'm sure that the [change](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156210/280) was introduced in 10.0. Do you get other result with version 10.0?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov hm... sorry for sticking my foot in this. I was just trying to be helpful; I didn't realize it was contested.  (I get `True` in 10.1.0 under Windows x64, for what it's worth.)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You are right. There's something weird: copy-pasting an image from 10.4+ to 10.3- loses (actually: flattens) the alpha channel.  Copy-pasting an image from 10.3- to any 10.0+ version does retain the alpha channel.  (This is at least what happens on OS X.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I also faced this: copying the image from version 11.2.0 and pasting into versions 8.0.4, 9.0.1 and 10.0.1 results in transparency being flattened, but with version 10.4.1 its OK. That's why I rely only on `Import` for testing and also check the result with `ColorSeparate`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please add it.  At the present time this list is a manageable size and I believe it is better to tend toward exhaustiveness.  If at some point it becomes unmanageable it may be better to remove such things to a separate post.

Comment: I think ``LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber`` changed in between 11.1 and 11.2.

Comment: Thanks @Chip I have only 11.3 now and didn't notice before.

Comment: @johu The description "`$MachinePrecision` is the new default" is incorrect. Aside from those I've added in the community wiki, notice `$MachinePrecision` and `$MachinePrecision` are different, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117939/1871) for more information.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! I admit I still to do not understand the fully story, but thought that even incomplete hint to the problem is better than none. I have struggled a lot getting my old code back the stability and performance. Note the typo in your comment... I guess you wanted to say: `MachinePrecision` and `$MachinePrecision` are different.

Comment: @Johu Oops… Yes, I mean `$MachinePrecision` and `MachinePrecision` are different.