# PlotLegends -> "Expressions" not working when Plot given one function

Tags: plotting, legending, version-10

I don't get a legend when I use the option `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` when the first argument to Plot is a single function. It works OK when I give `Plot` a list of functions.

Test cases:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]
**===================================**
[image]

Comment: I can confirm that in V10 `PlotLegends` fails when `Plot` is given a single simple argument such as `Sin[x]`, and this worked in V9. I tested on OS X. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I have sent a report on this issue to WRI tech support.

Comment: @m_goldberg not a bug. I'll explain below.

Comment: In which version of Windows (7 or 8) is V10 installed?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I used Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an intentional change to make `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` more consistent with `PlotLegends -> Automatic`. Both now do not produce legends when only one line is present. What you are looking for is `PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"` which has the old behavior, e.g.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"]
```

[image]

More generally, `PlotLegends` operates based on whether or not two plots are distinguishable.  In other words, if there is no displayed difference between two plots, two legends won't be displayed. For example,

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Contrast this with

```
Table[
 Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLegends -> legend, PlotLabel -> legend],
 {legend, {"AllExpressions", All, "Placeholders", {a, b}}}
]
```

[image]

After the number of distinguishable plots are determined, that gives you the number of legends to expect, once the no single legend rule is accounted for. So, these all should give two legends,

```
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
Table[
 Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}, 
   PlotLegends -> legend, PlotLabel -> legend],
 {legend, {"AllExpressions", All, "Placeholders", {a, b}}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. It is very edifying. It is also an indictment of the V10 documentation of `PlotLegends`, which mentions none of the new behavior you discuss. It doesn't even mention that `PlotLegends` has been modified in V10

Comment: @m_goldberg yes, and that has been reported as well.

Comment: @m_goldberg I fleshed it out a hair, as it felt incomplete.

Comment: In my opinion, it would have been better to maintain the old behavior of `"Expressions"` and instead add a new option `"DistinctExpressions"` for the behavior that we're now seeing. With the change as you describe it here, users have to go through their notebooks and hand-edit them to replace the old with the new option `"AllExpressions"` if they want a single-line legend. Seems like an unnecessary hassle.

Answer (score 4):

I received an answer to the report I filed with WRI tech support on this issue. I think there might some interest it what it said, so I quote the relevant part:

> There is some change of behavior for PlotLegends->"Expressions". If you want to generate legends for each function, you can use
>
> $\ \ \ \ \ \ $Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"]
>
> So this is more of an issue of documentation and I have updated the bug report with this case.