# Does PlotLegends not work in MM 11?

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending

I literally just downloaded MMA11 and upgraded from MMA 10.4, and `PlotLegends` seems to not work the way it did previously... Kind of annoying. Anyone knows why?

```
 Clear[var, expr, blah, g, derivatives];
 var = Input["Type a variable, such as x, in this window."];
 expr = Input["Type an expression to be differentiated in the variable you just typed in the last window."];
 g[blah_] = expr /. {var -> blah};
 derivatives := {g[var], g'[var]}
 Plot[{derivatives}, {x, -3, 5}, {PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotLabel -> "A function and its Derivative", PlotRange -> 10}]
```

Comment: Do you have a more minimal example demonstrating this that doesn't reply on Input statements?

Comment: Try changing `Plot[{derivatives},...]` into `Plot[Evaluate@derivatives,...]`

Comment: It works PERFECTLY fine on 10.3.. I have both versions and just ran the same exact code.

Comment: @corey979 ok that fixes it... is that not a bug?? why would it work that well in 10.3 but then in 11 it doesn't work

Comment: Your code (without `Evaluate`) doesn't work for me on v10.4.1. // It's not a bug, it's a normal behaviour.

Comment: Make sure you upgrade to 11.0.1 if you have 11.0.0.

Comment: Correction: yep its a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, this is not a bug in `PlotLegends`. You can tell because the plot itself is using the color for a single data set, implying that it thinks there is only one ***multi-valued*** function present. Since `PlotLegends` with `"Expressions"` or `Automatic` is [sensitive to the number of functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56862/52), they will not display a legend when only one is present. The issue is then with how `Plot` is interpreting `derivatives`.

After a little experimentation, it comes down to the use of `SetDelayed` vs `Set`.  When `Set` is used to define the variable,

```
d1 = {Sin[x], Cos[x]}
Plot[d1, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

the expected image is produced.

But, when `SetDelayed` is used,

```
d2 := {Sin[x], Cos[x]}
Plot[d2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

it does not.  There was some work on the parser between 10.3 and 10.4 which is likely causing this change in behavior, but I am not inclined to consider this a bug. Simply, with `SetDelayed` the function is expected to be evaluated over and over again, and should be thought of as the equivalent of using

```
f[x_] := {Sin[x], Cos[x]}
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

which generates a plot identical to `d2`.

**Correction**: after looking at this again, and actually running this with `PlotLegends` with `Set` being used shows the same behavior. Therefor, I would say it is a bug.

Comment: I have the same problem - does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you add Evaluate to the expression to be plotted there it works. Must be some bug in Plot.

[image]