# How can I restore the old ImageCompose behaviour?

Tags: bugs, image-processing, compatibility, opacity

**Bug fixed in 11.3**

---

**Update**

This issue caught me out again so I contacted support once more. They have confirmed that the development team considers the new behaviour to be correct and claim that "ImageCompose uses standard Duff-Porter definitions".

I think the development team are mistaken about the standard definitions, however it looks like the new behaviour is here to stay.

---

Prior to version 10, if `ImageCompose` was used to overlay a partially transparent image region over a completely transparent image region, the result would keep the colour of the overlay. Like this:

[image]

Notice how the upper part of the red circle in the result is the **same** colour as the original red circle.

In version 10 the behaviour changed to this:

[image]

Notice that the upper part of the red circle in the result is now **darker** than the original.

I reported this as a bug to Wolfram Research, pointing out that the new behaviour was at odds with the documentation (the first image above is actually a [wayback machine snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20140828140247/http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCompose.html) of the version 10.0.0 documentation.)

Wolfram Research confirmed the bug and I was hopeful that version 10.0.1 would see it fixed. Unfortunately instead of reverting the functionality of `ImageCompose` they have merely updated the documentation to reflect the new behaviour (the second image above is a snapshot of the version 10.0.1 documentation).

I'm not sure if this is now considered a bug or a change in functionality, but in either case I would like some way to get the old behaviour back. Any ideas?

For testing you can use this code to recreate the example from the documentation:

```
i1 = SetAlphaChannel[
  Image[Blue]~ImageResize~100,
  Image@LowerTriangularize@ConstantArray[1, {100, 100}]]

i2 = SetAlphaChannel[
  Image[Red]~ImageResize~100,
  Image[0.5 DiskMatrix[40, 100]]]

ImageCompose[i1, i2]
```

Comment: Well, that's certainly undesirable! Alpha compositing [is supposed to be associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Analytical_derivation_of_the_over_operator) (`i0~ImageCompose~(i1~ImageCompose~i2)` should equal `(i0~ImageCompose~i1)~ImageCompose~i2`) and this doesn't do that. One could implement correct alpha compositing manually using `ImageApply`, but let's see if someone has a better way.

Comment: I imagine that the documentation was updated just as a result of an automatic processing, and not to show a new/different functionality. Just to make sure that WR will eventually correct the function to our expectations, I think you should send a bug report update, stating that now, not only the function is giving the wrong result, but also the documentation is showing the bug ;-)

Comment: @Rahul It would be nice if you post such an implementation.

Comment: @Alexey Sorry, I don't have the time to do it right now, but the definition of the "over" operator is on the Wikipedia page if you want to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The $over$ operator correctly implemented

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Analytical_derivation_of_the_over_operator), when composing $A$ $over$ $B$, the output alpha channel value $\alpha_O$ and the output color channel value $C_O$ are calculated as follows:

$\begin{cases}\alpha_O = 1 - (1 - \alpha_A) (1 - \alpha_B) 
\\C_O = \frac{\alpha_A C_A + (1 - \alpha_A)\alpha_B C_B}{\alpha_O},  \text{if $\alpha_O \neq 0$}
\\C_O = 0, \text{if $\alpha_O = 0$}
\end{cases}$

where $\alpha_A$ and $\alpha_B$ are alpha channel values of $A$ and $B$, and $C_A$ and $C_B$ – color channel values of $A$ and $B$ correspondingly.

This can be directly implemented in *Mathematica* 11.1 or above as follows:

```
imageCompose[b_Image, a_Image] := 
 Module[{alphaA = AlphaChannel@a, alphaB = AlphaChannel@b, alphaO, 
         cA = RemoveAlphaChannel@a, cB = RemoveAlphaChannel@b},
  alphaO = 1 - (1 - alphaA) (1 - alphaB);
  SetAlphaChannel[(alphaA*cA + (1 - alphaA) alphaB*cB)/alphaO, alphaO]]
```

Let us check the associative property:

```
{{i0, i1, i2}} = ImagePartition[
  Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13gh.png"], {Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1]}]

{i0~imageCompose~(i1~imageCompose~i2), (i0~imageCompose~i1)~imageCompose~i2}
Equal @@ %
ColorSeparate /@ %%
```

> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]
>
> ```
> True
> ```
>
> [image: output]

It holds! So what is the problem with `ImageCompose` of version 10 and later?

### Current implementation of `ImageCompose`: the diagnosis

When writing the above implementation for the first time I unintentionally made a simple mistake: I forgot to divide the output value for the color channel by $\alpha_O$. Here is what happened:

```
imageComposeWrong[b_Image, a_Image] := 
 Module[{alphaA = AlphaChannel@a, alphaB = AlphaChannel@b, alphaO, 
         cA = RemoveAlphaChannel@a, cB = RemoveAlphaChannel@b},
  alphaO = 1 - (1 - alphaA) (1 - alphaB);
  SetAlphaChannel[alphaA*cA + (1 - alphaA) alphaB*cB, alphaO]]

{i0~imageComposeWrong~(i1~imageComposeWrong~i2), 
 (i0~imageComposeWrong~i1)~imageComposeWrong~i2}
Equal @@ %
ColorSeparate /@ %%
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
> False
> ```
>
> [image: output]

The output looks exactly the same as for the current `ImageCompose`:

```
{i0~ImageCompose~(i1~ImageCompose~i2), (i0~ImageCompose~i1)~ImageCompose~i2}
Equal @@ %
ColorSeparate /@ %%
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
> False
> ```
>
> [image: output]

Numerical comparison reveals tiny differences due to rounding off errors. But the final diagnosis is clear: the developer just forgot to divide the color channel by the alpha channel!

It is a great shame that during more than three years after the release of version 10.0.0 nobody noticed this in the company! Do they themselves use this functionality – or not?!

**Please, do not be lazy to report this to the technical support, so that this shameful bug will be fixed as soon as possible! A high priority is given to bugs, which many users write about...**

### The remedy

From the above considerations the remedy is obvious: we must just divide the color of the `ImageCompose` output by the alpha channel:

```
icFix[img_Image] := img/AlphaChannel[img];

{i0~icFix@*ImageCompose~(i1~icFix@*ImageCompose~i2), (i0~icFix@*ImageCompose~i1)~icFix@*ImageCompose~i2}
Subtract @@ % // MinMax
ColorSeparate /@ %%
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
> {-3.10689*10^-6, 3.08454*10^-6}
> ```
>
> [image: output]

As one can see, there are still tiny differences due to rounding-off errors, but the associative property in fact is restored and the output is correct!

---

### Original answer

Citing a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60048/how-can-i-restore-the-old-imagecompose-behaviour#comment171186_60048) by [Rahul](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul):

> Well, that's certainly undesirable! Alpha compositing is [supposed to be associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Analytical_derivation_of_the_over_operator) (`i0~ImageCompose~(i1~ImageCompose~i2)` should equal `(i0~ImageCompose~i1)~ImageCompose~i2`) and this doesn't do that. One could implement correct alpha compositing manually using `ImageApply`, but let's see if someone has a better way.

Indeed, in versions 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 `ImageCompose` **is** associative:

```
$Version

{{i0, i1, i2}} = ImagePartition[
  Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13gh.png"], {Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1]}]

{i0~ImageCompose~(i1~ImageCompose~i2), (i0~ImageCompose~i1)~ImageCompose~i2}

Equal @@ %

ColorSeparate /@ %%
```

> ```
> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"
> ```
>
> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]
>
> ```
> True
> ```
>
> [image: output]

... while starting from version 10.0 it is not:

```
$Version

{{i0, i1, i2}} = ImagePartition[
  Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13gh.png"], {Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1]}]

{i0~ImageCompose~(i1~ImageCompose~i2), (i0~ImageCompose~i1)~ImageCompose~i2}

Equal @@ %

ColorSeparate /@ %%
```

> ```
> "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 9, 2014)"
> ```
>
> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]
>
> ```
> False
> ```
>
> [image: output]

It is also worth to note that despite that `Overlay[{i0, i1}]` and `Show[i0, i1]` look the same as the old `ImageCompose[i0, i1]`, they are not the same. But they do (approximately) equal to each other and do approximately hold the associative property:

```
$Version

overlayCompose[i0_, i1_] := Rasterize[Overlay[{i0, i1}], "Image", Background -> None];
showCompose[i0_, i1_] := Rasterize[Show[i0, i1], "Image", Background -> None];

{overlayCompose[i0, i1], showCompose[i0, i1], i0~ImageCompose~i1}

ColorSeparate /@ %

{i0~overlayCompose~(i1~overlayCompose~i2), (i0~overlayCompose~i1)~ overlayCompose~i2}

ColorSeparate /@ %

{i0~showCompose~(i1~showCompose~i2), (i0~showCompose~i1)~showCompose~ i2}

ColorSeparate /@ %
```

> ```
> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"
> ```
>
> [image: outout]
>
> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]

As one can see from the above, `Overlay` introduces artifact at the top, while `Show` does not.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough investigation. It would be great if your bug report gets the code fixed, but I'm not hopeful. The second time I reported this they acknowledged the non-associative behaviour but considered it correct.

Comment: Reported to the support as [CASE:3967986]. Published on the Wolfram Community: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1212695

Comment: @SimonWoods It seems the bug is fixed in version 11.3.

Answer (score 11):

You can get the old `ImageCompose` behavior by using [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html?q=Overlay) instead:

```
Overlay[{i1, i2}]
```

> [image: Overlay]

---

### Edit:

As pointed out by the comment by [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov) the `Head` of an `Overlay` is "Overlay" and therefore doesn't match the `Head` of `ImageCompose`, which is "Image". I didn't realize this, because exporting to a .png file did handle the transformation.
One can use e.g.

```
ImportString@ExportString[Overlay[{i1, i2}], "PNG"]
```

to get an object with `Head` "Image", and that therefore can be used the same way as an object created with `ImageCompose` inside the notebook.

Comment: Unfortunately it only looks like `ImageCompose`, but it doesn't produce a new image. May be with further `Rasterize`?

Comment: `Head` is `Graphics`, however it works as an image for all image-processing functions that I tried! For example, `ImageResize[#, Scaled[1]] &@` produces "real" image with `Image` head.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. The Export-Import conversion seems to remove the alpha channel though. However I can rasterize direct to `Image` and maintain the alpha channel using `Rasterize[Overlay[{i1, i2}], "Image", Background -> None]`. I have some tests to run but this looks good so far.

Comment: @SimonWoods Using `Rasterize` with this options seems to be the best way. However, I'd like to add that `ImportString@
 ExportString[Overlay[{i1, i2}], "PNG", Background -> None]` also seems to preserve the alpha channel.

Comment: This solution seems robust - I can't find a way to break it! And it's faster (and probably more accurate) than post-processing the result from broken `ImageCompose`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

As well Karsten's solution using `Overlay`, technical support pointed out that `Show` can be used in the same way:

```
Rasterize[Show[i1, i2], "Image", Background -> None]
```

(Show converts the images to Raster expressions and overlays them in Graphics).

In both cases the alpha compositing is done by the front end, which uses the conventional associative "over" operator.

Comment: Also `Image@Show[i1, i2]`?

Comment: @mathe `Image` doesn't allow to pass the `Background -> None` option.