# BSplineFunction returns unevaluated when its degree is equal to the number of control points

Tags: functions, bugs, splines

**Bug fixed in 13.0.0** [CASE:4855260]

---

It seems that `BSplineFunction` always returns unevaluated without warnings, when its degree is equal to the number of control points (I'm using *Mathematica* 12.3.1):

```
n = RandomInteger[{2, 100}];
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
f = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n]
f[.5]
```

[image: screenshot]

Why does this happen?

Note that it works as expected with degrees higher than the number of control points:

```
n = RandomInteger[{5, 100}];
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
functs = Table[BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n + i], {i, -3, 3}];
Through[functs[.5]]
```

> [image: out]

Also notice that for degrees higher than `n` the outputs are equal to the output for degree `n - 1`:

```
n = RandomInteger[{5, 100}];
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
functs = Table[BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n + i], {i, -1, 100}];
Equal @@ Drop[Through[functs[.5]], {2}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

So it looks like degrees higher than `n - 1` are reduced to `n - 1`. But why then for `n` it returns unevaluated? Is it a bug?

Comment: Documentation `BSplineFunction` says  "The dimension of the manifold represented by BSplineFunction[array] is given by ArrayDepth[array]-1. The lengths of the lists that occur at the lowest level in the array define the embedding dimension.". Perhaps that's the reason why your test only works up to `SplineDegree->n-1` .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann But it also works with higher and lower degrees, for example `SplineDegree -> n + 1` and higher! The only exception is when the degree is exactly equal to the number of points.

Comment: Reported to support as [CASE:4855260].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update 2

I received a response to [CASE:4886321] (about the case of `SplineClosed -> True`):

> Mathematica is working as designed here.
>
> For n points, the max degree of polynomial basis one can get is n - 1.

I'm still unsure that it is correct for `SplineClosed -> True`, at least for an arbitrary value of the `SplineKnots` option, including both  `SplineKnots -> "Clamped"` and `SplineKnots -> "Unclamped"` variants. There already were cases when Wolfram Technical support incorrectly rejected obvious bugs ([a bright example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60048/how-can-i-restore-the-old-imagecompose-behaviour/156283#comment417273_156283)). If you have expertise in this area, please post an answer here.

### Update

The original bug is fixed in version 13.0.0. But now even for `SplineClosed -> True` `BSplineFunction` retuns for `SplineDegree -> n` the result identical to `SplineDegree -> n - 1`:

```
n = RandomInteger[{5, 100}];
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
i = Random[];
BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n, SplineClosed -> True][i] ===
 BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n - 1, SplineClosed -> True][i]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

In the version 12.3.1 these results were different (and both numerical):

```
n = RandomInteger[{5, 100}];
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
i = Random[];
BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n, SplineClosed -> True][i]
BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n - 1, SplineClosed -> True][i]
```

> ```
> {0.527505, 0.437591}
> ```

> ```
> {0.52804, 0.433405}
> ```

I think that the way the original bug was fixed has introduced another bug. Reported as [CASE:4886321].

---

### Original answer

I received a response from the support ([CASE:4855260]):

> Thank you for taking the time to send your report.
>
> I have forwarded an issue report to our developers in BSplineFunction
> with the information you provided, and added your contact information
> to the report so that you can be notified when it is resolved.
>
> We are always interested in improving Mathematica, and I want to thank
> you once again for bringing this issue to our attention. If you run
> into any other problems with any of our products or have any
> additional questions, please do not hesitate to contact us.

I consider this as a confirmation that I faced a bug.

Another interesting observation is that with the option `SplineClosed -> True` `BSplineFunction` retuns numerical result for `SplineDegree -> n` (where `n` is the number of control points), but for higher values of `SplineDegree` it returns results equal to the output for `SplineDegree -> n - 1`, not `SplineDegree -> n`:

```
n = RandomInteger[{5, 100}];
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
functs = Table[
   BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n + i, SplineClosed -> True], {i, -1, 100}];
Equal @@ Drop[Through[functs[RandomReal[]]], {2}]
Equal @@ Through[functs[RandomReal[]]]
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
> ```

I consider this as another, closely related bug.

Comment: Have you already reported this new development?

Comment: Reported as [CASE:4886321].

Comment: @J.M. I've got a response: "Mathematica is working as designed here. For n points, the max degree of polynomial basis one can get is n - 1." It is for the case `SplineClosed -> True`. Do you agree?

Comment: @J.M. Since you have some expertise in splines, I ask you to comment on the case described in the "Update 2" section.