# Incompatibility of CountryData[] between v. 9.0 and 10.1

Tags: curated-data, geography

There seems to be an incompatibility between the representation in `CountryData[]` for versions 9.0 and 10.1.  The documentation on `ref/CountryData` gives the following example, which does not work on 10.1:

```
Graphics[{If[CountryData[#, "AntarcticNations"], Orange, LightBrown], 
    CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ CountryData[]]
```

which does not produce the bi-colored map illustrated on the documentation.

My below code worked fine in v. 9.0, but does not yield a bi-colored map in v. 10.1, suggesting that the representation of `CountryData` has changed, thereby making the `MemberQ` coloring selection in `myMap` inoperable.

```
myCountries = 
  Sort[{"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "BosniaHerzegovena", 
    "Cambodia", "Canada", "China", "Croatia", "CzechRepublic", 
    "Denmark", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "Finland", "France", "Germany", 
    "Greece", "HongKong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", 
    "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Mexico", "Montenegro", 
    "Nepal", "Netherlands", "NewZealand", "Norway", "Peru", "Russia", 
    "SaudiArabia", "Singapore", "Slovenia", "Slovakia", "SouthKorea", 
    "Spain", "SriLanka", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", 
    "Thailand", "UnitedArabEmerites", "UnitedKingdom", 
    "UnitedStates", "VaticanCity"}];
myMap = Graphics[{If[
       MemberQ[myCountries, CountryData[#]], Blue, Orange],
      CountryData[#, {"SchematicPolygon", "LambertAzimuthal"}]} & /@ 
    CountryData[ ]];
myCaptionText = 
  Graphics[{Purple, 
    Text[StyleForm[
      StringJoin["The ", ToString[Length[myCountries]], 
       " countries I have visited"], 20]]}, {0, 0}];
myStringSet = Partition[StringJoin[#, ""] & /@ myCountries,
   Round[ Length[myCountries]/8], 
   Round[ Length[myCountries]/8], {1, 1}, " "];
myCountryLabels = Graphics[Text[myStringSet, {0, -1}]];
myCountriesMap = 
 Show[myMap, myCaptionText, myCountryLabels, ImageSize -> {600, 600}]
```

[image]

In v. 9.0 the countries in the list `myCountries` were rendered in Blue.

How can I restore that functionality?

Answer (score 5):

Change the `MemberQ` criteria to `CountryData[#, "Name"]]`

EDIT: Added spaces to some names in `myCountries` and corrected spellings.

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
myCountries = 
  Sort[{"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
    "Cambodia", "Canada", "China", "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
    "Ecuador", "Egypt", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong",
     "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy",
     "Japan", "Mexico", "Montenegro", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
    "Norway", "Peru", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Singapore", "Slovenia", 
    "Slovakia", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sweden", "Switzerland", 
    "Taiwan", "Thailand", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", 
    "United States", "Vatican City"}];

myMap = Graphics[{
      If[
       MemberQ[myCountries, CountryData[#, "Name"]],
       Lighter[Blue, .4],
       LightOrange],
      CountryData[#,
       {"SchematicPolygon", "LambertAzimuthal"}]} & /@
    CountryData[]];

myCaptionText = Graphics[{
    Purple,
    Text[StyleForm[
      StringJoin["The ", ToString[Length[myCountries]], 
       " countries I have visited"], 20]]},
   {0, 0}];

myStringSet = 
  Partition[StringJoin[#, ""] & /@ myCountries, Round[Length[myCountries]/8],
   Round[Length[myCountries]/8],
   {1, 1}, " "];

myCountryLabels = Graphics[Text[myStringSet, {0, -1}]];

myCountriesMap = 
 Show[myMap, myCaptionText, myCountryLabels, ImageSize -> {600, 600}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... that works as well, and is just a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer.  Countries now use `Entity["Country", #] & /@ myCountries`, and the conditional statement should compare `Entities`.

Comment: David, do you think some note of this should be made [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/121)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Fair point.  I posted a teeny comment to that effect.