# New behavior of PlotRange in Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting, options

In *Mathematica* 10, when I plot data that has small changes around some non-zero value, the plot chooses a `PlotRange` that "collapses" the data so that the variations cannot be seen.  The only way I can find to reproduce the results seen in prior versions is to manually set the `PlotRange`.  Is this a bug? Is there a way to redefine the function that computes `PlotRange`?

Here is a simple example of the problem I have.

```
dat = {{7.36107564302725094634299*^-8,6.49517319445169858694755},   
       {1.872486493499905555253878*^-7,6.495173287782000920228519}, 
       {3.295280057690389061023151*^-7,6.495173324963207553515714},
       {4.742955045429201620632748*^-7,6.495173299191079237788739}, 
       {5.950099990519129421821797*^-7,6.495173215270764724855183},
       {6.695807917858125246686823*^-7,6.495173088580509534386944}, 
       {6.843647194344045088159516*^-7,6.495172942307050194820725}};

ylim = {Min[#], Max[#]} &[#[[2]] & /@ dat]

ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> {All, ylim}]
```

[image]

In *Mathematica* version 9

```
ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: v9]

Comment: Greg, it seems to me that Mr. Wizard's exhaustive answer below solved your problem. You might consider marking his answer as accepted by clicking the grey check mark next to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some spelunking it appears I have an answer and solution: the behavior is as intended, and it is controlled by a [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html) option `"AllowMicroRanges"`.

```
ListLinePlot[dat,
  PlotRange -> Full,  
  Method -> {"AllowMicroRanges" -> #}
] & /@ {True, False}
```

[image]

It seems this option may also be given directly, outside of `Method`, but if you wish to control the default for this option without setting an overall `Method` you must set it for `` System`ProtoPlotDump`iListPlot `` or you get a "... is not a known option for ListLinePlot" message.

```
SetOptions[System`ProtoPlotDump`iListPlot, "AllowMicroRanges" -> True]
```

Comment: The `Plot` documentation has no *Method* section. Is there a list of available `Method` options somewhere (on this side or at wolfram.com)? Or is spelunking the only way to find them?

Comment: @Karsten The documentation shows that `Method` is one of the options of `Plot` and `ListPlot` but ends there as far as I know.  It seems that often `Method` is not documented; I suspect it is primarily (intended to be) used by support to solve specific issues.  Spelunking `iListPlot` reveals this explicit list of methods: `{"ScalingFunctions", "MappingFunctions", "DomainMappingFunctions", "AxisPadding", "DomainPadding", "RangePadding", "PointSizeFunction", "AllowMicroRanges", "OptimizePlotMarkers", "DefaultMeshStyle"}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ``Options[System`ProtoPlotDump`iListPlot]`` makes me see them too.

Comment: @Karsten That gets most of them but it is not necessarily complete.  Where possible reading the implementation itself is more reliable.  In this case it reveals `"MappingFunctions"` and `"DomainMappingFunctions"`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thank you for the info about `Options[System`ProtoPlotDump`iListPlot]`. But how do I find some information (description) about this Options (try and error)?

Comment: @mrz I only know either trial and error, or reading the definition of ``System`ProtoPlotDump`iListPlot`` itself to see how the options are being used.  See [(1742)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/121) if you choose the latter.