# A bug and inconsistency in current image arithmetic operations?

Tags: image-processing, core-language, language-design, opacity

Let us start from a single-pixel RGBA image:

```
i = Image[{{{0., .4, .7, .8}}}, Real, ColorSpace -> "RGB"];
```

Multiplying by `.5` affects every channel including the alpha channel:

```
ImageData[ImageMultiply[i, .5]]
```

> ```
> {{{0., 0.2, 0.35, 0.4}}}
> ```

Multiplying by a single-pixel `Real` image with channel value `.5`:

```
ImageData[ImageMultiply[i, Image[{{.5}}, Real]]]
```

> ```
> {{{0., 0.2, 0.35, 0.8}}}
> ```

... doesn't affect the alpha channel! But why? Isn't this behavior inconsistent with the previous result?

But let us check the addition:

```
ImageData[ImageAdd[i, .5]]
ImageData[ImageAdd[i, Image[{{.5}}, Real]]]
```

> ```
> {{{0.5, 0.9, 1.2, 1.3}}}
>
> {{{0.5, 0.9, 1.2, 1.8}}}
> ```

Heh... What??? `.8 + .5 == 1.8`? This is both inconsistent with the above and obviously has a bug. I've checked this with versions 10.0.1 and 10.1.0 and found that the former returns `1.3` for the alpha channel while the latter returns `1.8`.

I'm at loss where is the intended behavior. Should arithmetic operations with images affect alpha channel? And should arithmetic operations between an image and a number affect alpha channel?

Comment: Could it be that both of these are due to the unanticipated use of multiplying and adding images with different colour spaces? That, along with the fact that alpha channels are often treated differently from the others might explain why it's the alpha channel that falls apart. (And it gets weirder -- adding `Image[{{.0}}, "Real"]` gives `{{{0., 0.4, 0.7, 1.8}}}`, So apparently, pretty much everything equals 1.8).

Comment: I guess the conversion of `Image[{{x}}]` to the RGBA color space gives `Image[{{{x, x, x, 1}}}]`. That seems a reasonable approach in most contexts, and explains the results.

Comment: @SimonWoods You are exactly right! `Trace` shows that at first is called `ColorConvert[Image[{{x}}], "RGB"]` and then ``Image`InsertTransparency[%, 1]``. The same is true for multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/a-bug-and-inconsistency-in-current-image-arithmetic-operations?noredirect=1#comment417293_156326) by [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) explains both the issues:

> I guess the conversion of `Image[{{x}}]` to the RGBA color space gives `Image[{{{x, x, x, 1}}}]`. That seems a reasonable approach in most contexts, and explains the results.

Checking with `Trace` (*Mathematica* 11.2.0):

```
Trace[ImageAdd[i, Image[{{.5}}, Real]], 
  ImageColorSpace | ColorConvert | Image`InsertTransparency] //. {{c__}} :> {c}
```

[image: screenshot]

The output for `ImageMultiply` is exactly the same.

What the output means? At first `ColorSpace`s for both images are determined and then the second one (for which `ColorSpace` isn't specified) is converted into the color space of the first using `ColorConvert`:

```
ColorConvert[Image[{{.5}}, Real], ImageColorSpace[i]]
```

> ```
> Image[RawArray["Real64", {{{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}}}], "Real", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True]
> ```

Then using undocumented function `` Image`InsertTransparency `` the alpha channel with value `1` is inserted into the output image:

```
Image`InsertTransparency[%, 1]
```

> ```
> Image[RawArray["Real64", {{{0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.}}}], "Real", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True]
> ```

As a result a non-transparent RGBA image is obtained from original grayscale one-channel image. With this image both multiplication and addition is performed channel-wise using correspondingly `` Image`CompositionOperationsDump`imageMultiply `` and `` Image`CompositionOperationsDump`imageAdd ``.

It is interesting that image division is performed by `` Image`CompositionOperationsDump`imageDivide `` which has default option `"IndeterminateValue"->1`. This option is documented on the Docs page for [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) under `Scope ► Arithmetic & Statistical Operations`.

So the bottom line is that arithmetic operations involving images always involve alpha channel, but one should keep in mind that for non-transparent images alpha channel is always assumed to be equal to `1` (starting from *Mathematica* 10.1.0).