# interpretation of <-> as UndirectedEdge in 11.2?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, syntax, packages, compatibility

I have a package developed in earlier versions of *Mathematica*. In it, I use the notation `x_ <-> y_` for undirected edges.

When I use this package in 11.2, *Mathematica* does not match `<->` to an undirected edge.

For example, if I define

```
edge2Distance[x_ <-> y_] := geoDistance[x, y]
```

in the package, it does not match a call like:

```
edge2Distance /@ EdgeList[g]
```

I could rewrite the entire package, but it would be bug-prone and the readability of something like this would not be great.

```
edge2Distance[UndirectedEdge[x_, y_]] := geoDistance[x, y]
```

Any ideas what could be done?

Comment: Worth to mention that the reason is probably a `TwoWayRule`.

Comment: Yep, that's probably an arguable choice: `EdgeList@Graph[{TwoWayRule[a, b]}]` --> `{a \[UndirectedEdge] b}`

Answer (score 5):

As Kuba notes, this is a recent breaking change; 11.2 now interprets `a <-> b` as `TwoWayRule[a, b]` instead of `UndirectedEdge[a, b]`.

You might want to define a new `EdgeList[]` function that will convert `UndirectedEdge[]` into `TwoWayRule[]`:

```
myEdgeList[g_Graph] := TwoWayRule @@@ EdgeList[g]
```

and then use `$VersionNumber` to help your code choose which version to use.

---

As Stephen Wolfram says in [the 11.2 release blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/09/14/its-another-impressive-release-launching-version-11-2-today/):

> Another language enhancement added in 11.2—though it's really more of a seed for the future—is `TwoWayRule`, input as `<->`. Ever since Version 1.0 we've had `Rule` (`->`), and over the years we've found `Rule` increasingly useful as an inert structure that can symbolically represent diverse kinds of transformations and connections. `Rule` is fundamentally one-way: "left-hand side goes to right-hand side". But one also sometimes needs a two-way version—and that's what `TwoWayRule` provides.
>
> Right now `TwoWayRule` can be used, for example, to enter undirected edges in a graph, or pairs of levels to exchange in `Transpose`. But in the future, it'll be used more and more widely.

(This got too long for a comment.)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why this happens. As a workaround I will probably make a global replace of <-> to ~UndirectedEdge~

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible workaround, if it is not already the case, add Kernel/init.m to your package.

```
 MyPackage
  |  ...
  |- MyPackage.m
  |- Kernel
      |  ...
      |- init.m
```

While normally `init.m` contains:

```
<< MyPackage`MyPackage`
```

you will change it:

```
Block[{TwoWayRule = UndirectedEdge},
    << MyPackage`MyPackage`
]
```

And this should fix it. `init.m` is the first thing that loads if it exists in the package.

It is limited to things that evalaute during package loading, such as *lhs* of set delayed here.

It will work until `TwoWayRule` is `Locked` but it probably won't be so don't worry and now it only is `Protected`.

Here is a quick check of this method:

```
ClearAll[f];
Block[{TwoWayRule = UndirectedEdge},
   Get@StringToStream@"f[a_<->b_]:=Column[{a,b}]"
]

?f
```

[image]