# How does Hash calculate hash for strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, hashing

I have this code

```
Hash["a","SHA"]
Hash[ToCharacterCode["a"],"SHA"]
```

and I was expecting to get the same result, but somehow it is different.

My question is: how does Mathematica calculate hashing for strings? From common sense it should convert a string to integer and calculate it for some integer. If so, how does it convert the string to integer?

Answer (score 13):

As of version 11.3.0, the documentation (and implementation) of [`Hash`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hash.html) have been updated.

When given a string, the hash algorithm works on the bytes of that string's UTF-8 representation.

For an example, below hashing the string `"a"` is the same as hashing the single byte 97 (decimal):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 5, 2018)" *)

Hash["a", "SHA"] === Hash[StringToByteArray["a"], "SHA"] === Hash[ByteArray[{97}], "SHA"]

(* True *)
```

It is also worth noting that unlike previous versions, `ByteArray` does have a special meaning and the hashing is performed directly on the underlying bytes.

That applies for all hash types except the one argument form `Hash[e]` which can also be specified as `Hash[e, "Expression"]`.

**Addendum**

Per @Kuba's request, I am adding some code that allows reproducing the results of string hashing as done in previous releases (back to version 9 anyway).

That is, of course, nothing like the actual implementation, just a mock-up intended to give the same hash values.

It has no error checking to speak of and probably is slower than it needs to be.

```
Clear[byteHash, stringHash];

byteHash[bytes_List, method_: "MD5"] := If[$VersionNumber >= 11.3
  ,
  Hash[ByteArray[bytes], method]
  ,
  Module[{tmp = CreateTemporary[], hash},
   BinaryWrite[tmp, bytes];
   Close[tmp];
   hash = FileHash[tmp, method];
   DeleteFile[tmp];
   hash]
]

stringHash[str_?StringQ, method_: "MD5"] := 
 Module[{bytes, cc = ToCharacterCode[str]},
  bytes = Which[
    $VersionNumber >= 11.3, 
       ToCharacterCode[str, "UTF-8"],
    $VersionNumber >= 11.2 && Max[cc] >= 512, 
       ToCharacterCode[ToString[str, CharacterEncoding -> "ISO8859-1"]],
    $VersionNumber >= 9.0, 
       Mod[cc, 256],
    True, 
       $Failed];
  byteHash[bytes, method]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers. can you add how was it working for  pre V11.3?

Comment: @Kuba Maybe you should undelete your answer, it sounds right to me. The string needs to be rewritten in ISO8859-1, so that for example the single character \\[Alpha] would become 8 characters: \, [, A etc.

Comment: I will try to come back and review it later, I remember I deleted it because I was getting inconsistent results on Cloud vs Windows. I think I suspected that is only a matter of picking correct encoding here and there but somehow stopped investigating.

Comment: This is a discussion that followed the deletion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41380526#41380526

Comment: Unfortunately it did strange things in earlier versions, not to mention that those things happened to be different in 11.2 from 9.0-11.1 due to some bug fix in ExportString. I might still add an example, if only to show there were good reasons to move away from the previous scheme for 11.3 to something explainable and sustainable.

Comment: It seems that `Hash` for `ByteArray` was overloaded too, otherwise I'd get the same result for `Hash[ByteArray[{195, 153}], "SHA256"]` in V11.2 and V11.3, right? It is not the case. And due to that internal issuess and a bug you mentioned I think I will not undelete my answer. It would help a lot if you could find some time to elaborate on history of Hash for strings/byte arrays etc, many people need to support their packages for older versions too.

Comment: @Kuba Right, it's what I meant by "unlike previous versions, ByteArray ..."

Comment: Right, I missed that part from your recent answers. And thanks for answer, no wonder that I was failing to reveal the real flow.

Comment: Done: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167884/5478

Comment: @Kuba Curiously, an above comment of mine I did not delete seems to have disappeared, but that's fine. I made a half-comment/half-answer to your new question and now I'll definitely take a vacation from posting about Hash.

Comment: Yes, I deleted those three new comments one of which was yours as the matter was off topic and moved to linked question. Forgive me if you don't like this kind of interference. And sure, I am really grateful for your feedback.

Comment: @Kuba Not a problem, I figured it was something like that. The one saying "Done" seems a bit confusing without the context, of course.