# Incorrect calculating Hash SHA256

Tags: hashing, version-11.3

At the moment I'm using version 11.2. A few days ago, after an update in my programs, I found errors. It turned out that the new version incorrectly computes the hash. I'm using method SHA256. And here is an example of computing a hash that differs from the result in the previous version.

```
(* 11.2 *)
Hash["¥"]
```

> Out[..] := 756035385197879955

And the same in new version

```
(* 11.3 *)
Hash["¥"]
```

> Out[..] := 756035385197879955

But for method SHA256

```
(* 11.2 *)
IntegerString[Hash["¥", "SHA256"], 16]
```

> Out[..] := ac3ed5d81b09324e72933efee6365d9277132a857d324788842a83df908fe6b2

Another result for the new version

```
(* 11.3 *)
IntegerString[Hash["¥", "SHA256"], 16]
```

> Out[..] := 6922e93e3827642ce4b883c756b31abf80036649d3614bf5fcb3adda43b8ea32

This works for characters whose code is greater than 127. Are there ways to solve this problem? (the result for the new version I tested in in the wolfram cloud)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167633/hmac-correct-on-11-2-but-wrong-and-different-on-11-3-running-same-code). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I ran into this problem!

Comment: As far as I understand to keep consistent behavior across different versions you need to use: `Hash[ToString["¥", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"], ___]`, so patch the old code rather than patch new `Hash`. Current behavior should be more robust and older had few undocumented issues/inconsistencies attached anyway. See this question and the discussion after the answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167639/5478

Comment: @Kuba Funnily enough, this will actually fail for some characters due to the vagaries of ToString.  But I added an example to the other question that avoids it.

Answer (score 8):

The current SHA256 hash value is

```
Hash["¥", "SHA256", "HexString"]

(* "ac3ed5d81b09324e72933efee6365d9277132a857d324788842a83df908fe6b2" *)
```

which matches what you get from e.g. http://new.md5calc.com/hash-calc/sha256/%C2%A5 or from

```
$ echo -n ¥ | sha256sum
ac3ed5d81b09324e72933efee6365d9277132a857d324788842a83df908fe6b2  -
```

What is being hashed are the two bytes of the UTF-8 representation of the character ¥. See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167633/hmac-correct-on-11-2-but-wrong-and-different-on-11-3-running-same-code) previous answer for more details.

Comment: At the moment in the cloud everything works correctly (according with 11.2). Your alternative is a full equivalent of my.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have your two versions labeled backwards, because I see

```
In[21]:= IntegerString[Hash["¥", "SHA256"], 16] (* 11.3 *)
Out[21]= "ac3ed5d81b09324e72933efee6365d9277132a857d324788842a83df908fe6b2"

In[1]:= IntegerString[Hash["¥", "SHA256"], 16] (* 11.2 *)
Out[1]= "6922e93e3827642ce4b883c756b31abf80036649d3614bf5fcb3adda43b8ea32"
```

At any rate, there was a bug in in earlier versions where code points greater than 255 were simply truncated to their lowest 8 bits.  In 11.3, strings are hashed correctly according to their UTF-8 bytes.  You can use `` Developer`LegacyHash `` if you want bug-for-bug compatibility.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not mix up anything? In the question for 11.2 is hash value that you call correct.

Comment: I get 6922..., which is wrong, in 11.2, and ac3ed5..., which is correct (as mentioned by Ilian) in 11.3

Comment: Thanks for the Developer`LegacyHash tip! You are a savior sir! :D