# How has Hash changed in 11.3?

Tags: documentation, compatibility, hashing

There are already few topic related to `Hash[_String]`:

[How does Hash calculate hash for strings?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160589/5478)

[Incorrect calculating Hash SHA256](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167720/5478)

But it looks like changes are more severe:

`Hash[{}]` returns the same in V11.2 and V11.3, but e.g. `Hash[{}, "MD5"]` does not.

[image]

And I don't see an explanation in documentation:

[image]

What is the complete list of changes? How to make old code compatible with those changes?

Comment: `Hash["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "MD5"] // 
 Curry[BaseForm][16]`  (* 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6 *) matches Wikipedia MD5. So is it incorrect only for certain inputs?

Comment: [CASE:4030115] was created

Comment: Your answers helped me with a program I had. Today Premier Service gave me this, which is an easier solution for old code which needs to be maintained: ``Developer`LegacyHash[]`` Presumably they will keep the function in future versions. I decided to fix my code by switching to a `ByteArray[]` with the old prefix bytes added.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is already discussion about `String` and `ByteArray` in the linked previous [Q & A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160589/5478), so I'll comment a bit about general expressions.

This only concerns the named hash algorithms like `"MD5"` or `"SHA"` etc.

The single argument form `Hash[expr]`, which is equivalent to `Hash[expr, "Expression"]` is completely separate and based on the internal representation of `expr`. It has not been changed for 11.3.

Using [@Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s example of a very simple expression, in 11.3 we have the following new hash value

```
Hash[{}, "MD5"]

(* 68244457821771821570522625853545795031 *)
```

The previous hash value can still be obtained using

```
Developer`LegacyHash[{}, "MD5"]

(* 272934427398090264974473461931457450337 *)
```

Why the change? The previous scheme for converting expressions (to strings) for hashing had a number of severe problems.

For example, it did not take into account the contexts of symbols so it could happen that the same expression would hash to a different value because of a different `$ContextPath`, it had issues with evaluation leaks etc.

These have now been addressed, but the fixes mean the hash values would inevitably change. `` Developer`LegacyHash `` is provided for people who in some way depend on the old hash values.

The wording in the documentation isn't fully accurate, because `ToString[FullForm[expr]]` is not used literally.

What is actually true is that the input given to the hashing algorithm **is based on** the bytes of `ToString[Unevaluated[FullForm[expr]]]`, where all symbols in `expr` are qualified with their full contexts.

Furthermore, a constant 32-byte sequence prefix is added for (non-String and non-ByteArray) expressions to avoid collisions -- this ensures that the number `2` and the string `"2"` do not end up having the same hash value. This is because `ToString[Unevaluated[FullForm[2]]]` is the same as the string `"2"` but `2` and `"2"` are different expressions.

Below is a mock-up example (not the actual implementation) that could be used to replicate the 11.3 hash value even on earlier versions. It uses the `byteHash` utility defined in my previous [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167639/145).

```
prefix = {209, 74, 9, 190, 254, 30, 81, 99, 147, 98, 22, 44, 107, 239, 77, 113, 
          23, 185, 9, 18, 189, 28, 97, 183, 43, 63, 221, 103, 61, 127, 201, 101};

byteHash[Join[prefix, ToCharacterCode["System`List[]"]], "MD5"]

(* 68244457821771821570522625853545795031 *)
```

While the documentation ideally should give *some idea* of what serialization is used for general expressions, I would not hold the expectation that it must go into any deep level of detail or provide sufficient information to actually write an alternative implementation. Besides, the serialization could conceivably change some day again.

I think the moral is, if people want full control, they should themselves create a sequence of bytes to give as input to the hashing method in whatever way they see as appropriate. Then, what a named algorithm like `"MD5"` or `"SHA"` must return is fully determined, and a result different from that would certainly be a bug.

Comment: By the way, I think this post beat @halirutan's *greatly expanded* answer by about 3 minutes -- if I had actually seen his edit, I wouldn't have attempted my somewhat redundant answer.

Comment: Yeah, I still vote for an alarm that pops up when a WRI-dev is looking at a question :) I wouldn't have started digging but I wanted to be sure where the difference was coming from to make not false claims. But it's actually so nice having some of you guys around who can give so much more insight.

Comment: Thank you. I have a doubt: up to `Additionally, a constant 32-byte sequence prefix...`. Now, that paragraph says something which is not true, string bytes for `2` and `"2"` differ by quotes `""` because we use `FullForm` and if there were not, I don't see how constant prefix would fix this. But this may be related to my limited knowledge about hashing.

Comment: @Kuba Awkward wording which I’ll fix. The point is, "2" is a string, so it does not go through FullForm. But 2 would be hashed as "2" if not for the prefix.

Comment: Combining this with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119924/63067, ``byteHash[Block[{$ContextPath={}, $Context="NonExistingContext`"}, Join[prefix, ToCharacterCode[ToString[Unevaluated[FullForm[expr]]], "UTF-8"]]]`` appears to backport the newer hashes to older versions of Mathematica

Answer (score 16):

I guess the reason for that has nothing to do with the `"MD2"` or `"MD5"` sum, which hasn't changed. The reason is that the *input* you are feeding has changed. To create a hash from an expression, Mathematica needs to convert the expression into a serialized form that can be hashed.

### Details

Before we consider, what changed between version 11.2 and 11.3, let us first take a look at what happens when hashing expressions. As I said, when hashing an expression, it needs to be converted into bytes that are then hashed. Kuba pointed out the following information from the documentation

[image: img]

Trying this in version 11.2 gives 3 different hashes

```
e = {};
str = ToString[FullForm[e]];
bytes = StringToByteArray[str];
Hash[{}, "SHA1"]
Hash[str, "SHA1"]
Hash[bytes, "SHA1"]
(* 623731294305055464111497716552294880943817129159 *)
(* 574126028549497177030915842606154604998516284935 *)
(* 763583645927281726897351532107330233032372985102 *)
```

In version 11.3, at least the `str` and `bytes` hash is the same on my machine but only the `str` hash matches between the versions. This gives the clue, that we need to look at how bytes are constructed from an expression.

I'll leave the digging as an exercise for the interested reader. Between 11.2 and 11.3, a great deal of the hash implementation has changed. One of those changes is in

```
ImportExport`HashDump`exprToString
```

This function is responsible for turning an expression into a string. While in version 11.2 it only has one parameter: the expression, in version 11.3 it takes a second boolean argument *LegacyQ*.

Here is, what 11.2 gives me for `{}`

```
ImportExport`HashDump`exprToString[{}]
(* "ÑJ  ¾þ\.1eQcb\.16,kïMq\.17¹ \.12½\.1ca\[CenterDot]+?Ýg=ÉeList[]" *)
```

It contains a *prefix* string that is followed, indeed, by the full-form of `{}`. This prefix is the reason, why simply hashing the `FullForm` gives a different result. In version 11.2, you can therefore use

```
Hash[{}, "SHA1"]
Hash[ImportExport`HashDump`exprToString[{}], "SHA1"]
(* 623731294305055464111497716552294880943817129159 *)
(* 623731294305055464111497716552294880943817129159 *)
```

to get a string that hashes to the same value as the expression itself. In 11.3, things are more complicated since a string is further mangled by a

```
FromCharacterCode@ToCharacterCode[str, "UTF-8"]
```

step that changes the prefix. But this is not important right now, because the main difference is, that in 11.3 the transformation from expression to string changed. The standard `Hash` call does not use *LegacyQ*, but we can call the inner function and show the difference:

```
ImportExport`HashDump`toString[{}, #] & /@ {True, False}
(* {"List[]", "System`List[]"} *)
```

So 11.3 includes the context in the FullForm. This is the reason for the difference in the hashes when using expressions.

### Solution

In version 11.2 we had

```
Hash[{},#]&/@{"CRC32","SHA1","MD5"}//Column
(* 
2594213469
623731294305055464111497716552294880943817129159
272934427398090264974473461931457450337
*)
```

In version 11.3 you can achieve the same behavior by creating the string form in legacy mode and converting it correctly to a byte-array

```
hash[expr_, args__]:=With[{str=ImportExport`HashDump`exprToString[expr,True]},
  Hash[StringToByteArray[str,"ISO8859-1"],args]
]
hash[{},#]&/@{"CRC32","SHA1","MD5"}//Column
(* 
2594213469
623731294305055464111497716552294880943817129159
272934427398090264974473461931457450337 
*)
```

Comment: `"Expression"` is what `Hash[expr]` does so it does not apply to `MD5` case, right? Otoh, the next line says that `expr` to bytes conversion is done according to `ToString[FullForm[expr]]` - clearly not the case as for `{}` it is the same.

Comment: Summing up, at least documentation bug.

Comment: Well, that is a good point. I don't know. I *would* have expected, that it turns the expression into a serialized form and hashes the bytes with the MD5 algorithm. But your explanation makes sense too.

Comment: No, I have to disagree. If you try out different hashing algorithms with an expression, you get different hashes. At some point, the particular hashing method needs to play a role. The question is: How is the expression hashed or can we create the binary/string/internal representation that gives the same hash?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you disagree with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P3Nw.png - the documentation is misleading as `Hash[ToString[FullForm[{}]], "SHA"]` returns the same while `Hash[{}, "SHA"]` does not. Or I missed your point.

Comment: @Kuba Just for verbal clarity:  A *program* will have a *bug* while documentation will have an *error*. Think about it: Errors are made by writers (e.g. old fashioned "programmers" of text that is often not interpreted by machines) while bugs *crawl* into software by themselves! We have to be precise in our use of words ... ;-)

Comment: @gwr It is a convention we use to tag such cases. And I'd say you are only partially right, from user perspective it is a bug, Hash does not work   correctly according to documentation.

Comment: What the "Solution" offers is already provided by ``Developer`LegacyHash``. I thought @Kuba sounded more interested in how to generate the new hash values from old versions, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @ilian Yes, I saw that after your post, but I wasn't aware of this function. I was looking at the current implementation only.

Comment: BinarySerialize has nothing to do with Hash.  If you read tutorial/WXFFormatDescription, you'll likely be able to guess why the first byte in BinarySerialize has changed (answer: we incremented the format version when we added features to the format as we went from the experimental verision in 11.2 to the unexperimental version in 11.3).

Comment: @ItaiSeggev If you read my whole answer, you'll see that I have learned that by looking through the implementation. It is why I have given a detailed inspection on how hash works. However, as said in the *Preface* it was my first guess that not the hashing itself has changed, but what is fed to `Hash`.

Comment: I did read through your whole answer.  And I guess your stated "This serialized form of {} has changed from 11.2 to 11.3:" rather than "The ...", which is how I originally read it.  However, I still think the statement is highly misleading.  This has nothing to do with either in the internal representation of the expression, nor with how they are fed to byte hashes for consumption.  And in point of fact, the serialization the expression `{}` in BinarySerialize hasn't changed.  It is still `{102, 0, 115, 4, 76, 105, 115, 116}`.  It's only the version that has changed.

Comment: @gwr, "while bugs crawl into software by themselves!" - the programmer(s) wrote the software, so the programmer(s) introduced the bug.