# HMAC correct on 11.2 but wrong and different on 11.3 running same code

Tags: character-encoding, hashing, cryptography, version-11.3

If you run this code on 11.2

```
    hmacF[method_, message_, key_] := Module[

  {keyLen, dkey, opad, ipad, blocksize},

  blocksize =
   If[method === "SHA384" || method === "SHA512",
    128,
    64
    ];

  keyLen = StringLength[key];

  dkey = If[keyLen > blocksize,
    IntegerString[Hash[key, method], 16],
    StringPadRight[key, blocksize, FromCharacterCode[0]]
    ];

  {opad, ipad} = 
   FromCharacterCode[
      BitXor[ToCharacterCode@
        StringRepeat[FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16]], blocksize],
        ToCharacterCode@dkey]] & /@ {"5c", "36"};

  IntegerString[
   Hash[
    StringJoin[opad, 
     ExportString[
      IntegerDigits[Hash[StringJoin[ipad, message], method], 256], 
      "Binary"]],
    method],
   16, blocksize]
  ]
```

On something we know the answer to https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

```
hmacF["SHA256","symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559","NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"]
```

you get the correct answer

```
(*c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71*)
```

Run the same code on 11.3 and you get

```
(*88fdd5c8c2226ff025e290b37dec36d4bc6f84affb9928950fd865f9a0fd475e*)
```

Why the difference??  11.3 is not the correct HMAC result.

Comment: Well break the function down and find out which piece changed between versions... it's likely a single function giving a different output, my guess is `Hash`...

Comment: I tested it, 11.2 on desktop, 11.3 on cloud, and yes, `Hash` [seems to have changed in some manner](https://puu.sh/zEZDn/f84aa4dc0c.png)? If you think there is a bug, minimize it and report the issue to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Looking at the [`Hash`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hash.html) documentation page, there does seem to have been a handful of changes to the function for 11.3. Perhaps some of these adversely affected your code.

Comment: @user6014 I did read the documentation. None of the changes to Hash should have changed the output, hence my post. In your opinion, is it a bug?  Does my function need to be written differently in 11.3?  There should be no reason why the function needs to change.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the functionality, but I think the whole point of hashes are to be consistent? From my basic understanding of what's going on here I think it's at least raising to Wolfram's attention and having them comment on, unless someone else here can explain it.

Comment: Here is the minimal example demonstrating the difference: `Hash[ExportString[{217, 73, 200, 195, 231, 110, 83, 36, 139, 50, 62, 251, 63, 221, 85, 205, 192, 34, 244, 161, 198, 42, 132, 228, 7, 215, 112, 249, 161, 228, 204, 113}, "Binary"], "SHA256"]`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indeed, [`Hash`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hash.html) has changed for 11.3 in several ways.

The one relevant here is that strings are now hashed according to their UTF-8 representation.

As a simple example of the difference, consider the following string, which has only one character.

```
c = FromCharacterCode[217]; (* "\[CapitalUGrave]" *)
```

Its UTF-8 representation consists of the two (decimal) bytes `{195, 153}`, so in version 11.3 the hash would be computed from those two bytes, while in 11.2 the hash would be computed from the single (decimal) byte `217`.

Then the two corresponding hash results would be different, namely

```
(* new hash value *)
Hash[c, "SHA256"]
Hash[StringToByteArray[c], "SHA256"] 
Hash[ByteArray[{195, 153}], "SHA256"]

(*115129295529739515318262490854329296079790445441298973994137838100166123599005*)
(* or as a hex string: *)
(* fe88df3f083e08f99f796b5ba7f6eedbe14d45241cf5e0944caf17f55ac2349d *)
```

which agrees with various online hash calculators, e.g. http://new.md5calc.com/hash-calc/sha256/%C3%99 and

```
(* old hash value *)
Developer`LegacyHash[c, "SHA256"]
Hash[StringToByteArray[c, "ISO8859-1"], "SHA256"]
Hash[ByteArray[{217}], "SHA256"]

(* 11345241613194184164858110515603144575751235911333201083896508434490695406828*)
(* or as a hex string: *)
(* 19152ddfba193b5b09fcb80d1bba5248f36027c06e81670db5a7146fb654d4ec *)
```

where all inputs were evaluated with 11.3.0.

The `hmacF` implementation uses strings in a somewhat awkward way as data containers. It is easier to take advantage of several new `Hash` enhancements instead, like operating on byte arrays and returning the hashes in different formats.

For example,

```
hmacFnew[method_, message_, key_] := 
 Module[{dkey, dmsg, opad, ipad, blocksize}, 
  blocksize = If[method === "SHA384" || method === "SHA512", 128, 64];
  {dkey, dmsg} = StringToByteArray /@ {key, message};
  If[Length[dkey] > blocksize, dkey = Hash[dkey, method, "ByteArray"]];
  dkey = Normal[dkey];
  If[Length[dkey] < blocksize, dkey = PadRight[dkey, blocksize, 0]];
  {opad, ipad} = ByteArray[BitXor[dkey, ConstantArray[#, blocksize]]]& /@ {92,54};
  Hash[Join[opad,Hash[Join[ipad,dmsg], method, "ByteArray"]], method, "HexString"]
]

hmacFnew["SHA256", \
"symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.\
1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559", \
"NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"]

(* c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71 *)
```

If you don't feel like modifying your code, another way to get the previous behavior is to use `` Developer`LegacyHash ``, say

```
Block[{Hash = Developer`LegacyHash}, 
 hmacF["SHA256", 
  "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=\
0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559", 
  "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"]]

(* c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71 *)
```

Comment: I was on the way to posting a similar answer. Just one comment, the correct way of padding a key: `PadRight[Normal@
   If[keyLen > blocksize, 
    Hash[StringToByteArray@key, method, "ByteArray"], 
    StringToByteArray@key], blocksize, 0];`

Comment: Thanks @swish, I was just going by OP's code. I hope it looks correct now.

Comment: That part would be more elegant if `PadRight` and `BitXor` accepted byte arrays, but unfortunately they don't.

Comment: Thank you!  This was really throwing me for a loop.