# Generating Google BigQuery API Access Token in Wolfram Language

Tags: sql, query, security, api, authentication

I'm working on a Wolfram Language Package to connect into Google Bigquery (that I'll make public available). In order to finish It, I need to solve a last step, that is how to get an authentication token using JWT json file.

The package is working, but It's using R Script to generate the access token to be used in the Google Cloud API. Here the R code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

authPath <- "/Users/rodrigomurta/Desktop/GetBigQueryToken/bigquery.json"

googleEndpoint <-   httr::oauth_endpoint(
  base_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2",
  authorize = "auth",
  access = "token",
  validate = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo",
  revoke = "revoke"
)

jsonInfo <- jsonlite::fromJSON(authPath, simplifyVector = FALSE)

scope <- c(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
)
token <- httr::oauth_service_token(endpoint = googleEndpoint, secrets = jsonInfo, scope = scope)
token <- token$credentials$access_token

cat(token)
```

The returned token is something in this format:

```
ya29.c.KpEB4Af1KOjCjy-msEN42XFq0IqS2DGwDG85W_Rx9WXEF_W_vGGCnG0lklw7NU25UABnWjTkwB8_NdoDsRhHHyaBLC04Cgu2mKrJ-eLQ9qlWNkwOTlpIwFCOTc-Jj1QcHzMI4JwS-nC03MeIJIC75A8bIqAEKZx90SCseNYSAKjEKw30Dbnc6Oc2k8WYwlccDlJlIQ
```

I tried to explore `SecuredAuthenticationKey` function, but without success. It would be cool to have a 100% Mathematica implementation for both facilitate distribution and make possible to run  It inside Wolfram Cloud.

Some clue on how to do that?

Related:

- [How do I generate a JSON Web Token?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224080)
- [What is the best way to generate a JSON Web Token (JWT)?](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2004653)
- [BigQuery Package for Mathematica](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2176776)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform uses the **RS256** algorithm to send JWT and retrieve the tokens, all that is needed is to make a function that builds the JWT and creates a signature using `GenerateDigitalSignature[]`.

```
FixB64[str_?StringQ] := StringReplace[StringSplit[str, "="][[1]], {"+" -> "-", "/" -> "_"}];

EncodeBase64[str_?StringQ] := FixB64[Developer`EncodeBase64[str]];

JWTError::InvalidJWT = "``";

GetBigQueryToken[path_] := Module[{jsonkey, jhead, jreq, pkey, encrypted, url, res},

    PrintTemporary["Retrieving Token ", ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"]];

    (* Step 1: Open JSON File. *)
    jsonkey = Association[Import[path, "JSON"]];

    (* Step 2: Build "Header" JSON. *)
    jhead = EncodeBase64[ExportString[<|"alg" -> "RS256", "typ" -> "JWT"|>, "JSON", "Compact" -> True]];

    (* Step 3: Build "Payload" JSON. *)
    jreq = EncodeBase64[StringReplace[ExportString[<|"iss" -> StringTrim[jsonkey[["client_email"]]], "scope" -> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery", "aud" -> "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "iat" -> UnixTime[], "exp" -> UnixTime[] + 3600|>, "JSON", "Compact" -> True], "\\" -> ""]];

    (* Step 4: Open PrivateKey and Encrypt "Header" and "Payload" together. *)
    pkey = First[ImportString[StringTrim[jsonkey[["private_key"]]], "PEM"]];
    encrypted = FixB64[BaseEncode[GenerateDigitalSignature[jhead ~~ "." ~~ jreq, pkey][[1, -1]]]];

    (* Step 5: Build the URL. *)
    url = HTTPRequest[<|"Scheme" -> "https", "Domain" -> "oauth2.googleapis.com", "Path" -> "token", "Method" -> "POST", "ContentType" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Query" -> {"grant_type" -> "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", "assertion" -> jhead <> "." <> jreq <> "." <> encrypted}|>, VerifySecurityCertificates -> True];

    (* Step 6: Execute the POST Request. *)
    res = URLExecute[url];

    (* Handle JWT Errors. *)
    If[KeyExistsQ[res, "error"], Return[Message[JWTError::InvalidJWT, res[[2, 2]]]]];

    (* Step 7: Return as an Association. *)
    <|"Token" -> Iconize[res[[1, 2]], "Secret Token"], "Expires" -> Quantity[res[[2, 2]], "Seconds"], "Type" -> res[[3, 2]]|>

];
```

To get the BigQuery token, just do:

```
GetBigQueryToken["path_to_key.json"]
```