# FindFaces in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: image-processing, syntax, machine-learning, compatibility

I just upgraded to Mathematica 11.3. but now my `FindFaces` instructions do not work anymore.

I guess they changed the syntax in 11.3.

Here is the original code:

```
boxes = FindFaces[image, {190, Infinity}];
```

I want to find all faces in an image which are greater than a certain scale.
How can I do it in Mathematica 11.3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken V11.2 syntax:

```
FindFaces[image, {190, Infinity}];
```

in V11.3 can be achieved with

```
List @@@ FindFaces[image, {190, Infinity}, "BoundingBox"]
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, however, I got the following message: `FindFaces::oldsize: The syntax FindFaces[image, {min, max}] is obsolete and will not be supported in future versions of the Wolfram Language.`

Comment: @james This message is generated by the first line used in 11.3. The point of my answer is to replace it with the second line.