# Why this weird return value from `N`?

Tags: bugs, approximation

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and fixed in 12.0.**

Why does `N` just return the exact number below? I want a 2000 digit approximation...

```
N[
  Root[
    { 750 + 5*E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1) - 300*#1 - 2*E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1)*#1 - 5*E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1)*(Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1 + E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1)*(Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1^2 & 
    , 1.61954714423535277337584345129603991681`20.521825446421918
    }
  ]
, 2000
]
```

It works if I ask less precision. Is this behavior correct and if it is, how is the upper limit of precision that mathematica will compute defined?

Comment: I got an approximate value `1.6195471442353...` when I ran that code.

Comment: It works for me at 2000, but stops working when prec > 2003. I would report this to support.

Comment: Same for me with `prec >= 2004` (version 11.3, macOS).

Comment: Tested up to `100000`, and it works just fine for me (10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)).

Comment: `N[...., 100000]` works fine on `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`, but fails for $\geq$ `2003` on `11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

Comment: Bug not present in Mma 11.2 for Windows 64bits, at least for up to 10000 digits precision. Confirmed in Mma 11.3 for Windows for 2004 digits precision and more.

Comment: Works for up to 2003 on Mathematica 11.3 on a Windows 10 computer. prec>=2004 yields only precise results

Comment: Already fixed in the development version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @t-smart seems to suspect, the change in V11.3 to let machine underflows to underflow to `0.` is at the root of this bug.  In the OP's problem, *Mathematica* isolates the roots with rational numbers to the desired precision. It then uses the interval length to determine the precision argument to `N` to get the final result.  Unfortunately it uses machine precision to approximate the interval length, which underflows to `0.`. The resulting precision, based on `Log[0.]` is `Indeterminate`, which is an invalid precision argument for `N`.  This failure results in `N` returning unevaluated.

FWIW, a fix is to redefine `N` via the Villegas-Gayley trick:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{N},
 Unprotect[N];
 N[e_] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},
   With[{ne = N[e]},
    If[e != 0 && ne == 0.,
     N[e, $MachinePrecision],
     ne
     ]
    ]];
 Protect[N];
 N[Root[{750 + 5*E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1) - 300*#1 - 
      2*E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1)*#1 - 
      5*E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1)*(Log[3] - Log[5] + 
         Log[13])*#1 + 
      E^((Log[3] - Log[5] + Log[13])*#1)*(Log[3] - Log[5] + 
         Log[13])*#1^2 &, 
    1.61954714423535277337584345129603991681`20.521825446421918}], 
  2010]
 ]
(*
1.61954714423535277337906541500279581776848110660831546798133301726783\
...\
317430074329935276876493295501167507324563338238323  
*)
```

I cannot explain the threshold precision (which seems to be `Log10[2*^2003]`) for the bug.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this is a problem involving the numeric precision with Mathematica. Since I don't have the source code, my best guess is that somehow the rules dealing with `N` changed in the past update.
    `N[Khinchin, 2000]`
This code runs fine on Mathematica 11.2, giving a correct result. But on Mathematica 11.3, this is what it get:[image]
So in 11.3, MMA changed the rules and set a hard stop on the maximum digits. For your code, that is what happened,  `Root` gets onto the hard stop, thus putting an end to the calculation. The reason of this change is unknown. Speed improvements, I suppose?