# What functions work in which version of Mathematica

Tags: functions, version-9, compatibility, version-11

Is there any good documentation on which version will work (remained the same) in which version of *Mathematica*? Or at least an overview of when functions were introduced?

In this instance for example I would like to know who could be the culprit for some code not working on version 9 when it is functional in v11.

I expect that one of the following is new/altered since version 9:

`Select`, `FileNames`, `StringContainsQ`, `Or`, `StringJoin`, `ToString`.

Comment: At the bottom of the documentation page for each function in the help system there is an indication of when a function has been introduced, and when it was last modified, with version numbers. Would that help?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/4999

Comment: I once wrote a MMA script that creates a dataset with all possible incompatibilities of a given Wolfram Script (.wl or .m file): https://gist.github.com/JEM-Mosig/b58aa55e2da5ffcd5e29e6ac93c5ed5a

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
data = WolframLanguageData[{"Select", "FileNames", "StringContainsQ", 
    "Or", "StringJoin", "ToString"}, {"Name", "DateIntroduced", 
    "DateLastModified", "VersionIntroduced", "VersionLastModified"}];

TableForm[data, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Name", "DateIntroduced", 
    "DateLastModified", "VersionIntroduced", "VersionLastModified"}}]
```

[image]

So `StringContainsQ` is nonexistent in v9, hence it's the culprit.

Comment: +1 This is beautiful...

Answer (score 7):

`WolframLanguageData` has the answers you are looking for - specifically, versions in which symbols were introduced or modified!

```
symbols = 
 EntityValue[
  "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"Name", "FullVersionsModified", "VersionIntroduced"}]
```

This gives a list of the name of each symbol, the version numbers within which they were modified, and the versions in which they were introduced. For instance,

```
{"Capitalize", {"11.", "11.2"}, 10.1}
```

This shows that `Capitalize` was introduced in 10.1, and modified in 11 and 11.2.

Now you can `Select` subsets of these symbols, for instance by the version in which they were introduced:

```
Select[symbols, Last@# > 10 &]
```

This gives all symbols introduced after version 10.

Have a look at the documentation - there are many other properties for `WolframLanguageData`, hopefully it'll help!

Answer (score 5):

See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn11.html and the related pages on the bottom. This will tell you that StringContainsQ has been altered going from 10 to 11. This is probably the cause of the problem. These pages seem to be the best sources on the changes (although they are not very good).

---

(If someone knows a more comprehensive source that would be great, note some peculiarities of this source: The page on changes from 10.4 to 11.0 does not contain `StringContainsQ` while the one on new/altered functions in 11 does. Is there a reason for this?)