# MatrixConditionNumber does not work in version 12.0

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra, undocumented

```
A = {{1., 0.}, {0., 2.}};
LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[A]
```

Comment: Try ``LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber``.

Comment: See the “Between Versions 11.1 and 11.2” section [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56729/4346).

Answer (score 10):

After *@CarlWoll*'s comment:

You can search for undocumented functions by using [`Names`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html)

```
Names["*`" <> "MatrixConditionNumber" <> "*"]
(* {"LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber"} *)
```

Now calling the correct function name

```
A = {{1., 0.}, {0., 2.}};
LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber[A]
(* 2. *)
```